# Could not open a connection to your authentication agent

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-agent

I am running into this error of:

```
$ git push heroku master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.132' to the list of known hosts.
!  Your key with fingerprint b7:fd:15:25:02:8e:5f:06:4f:1c:af:f3:f0:c3:c2:65 is not authorized to access bitstarter.
```

I tried to add the keys and I get this error below:

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Comment: Question: once you've gone through EVERY answer on this page, and none of them work. What can you do next?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Try this one:

`$ ssh-agent /bin/sh`     and       
`$ ssh-add $yourkey`

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Next you should use `git config --list` to see if you have set `credential.helper` - if you have you should remove this setting, as the helper is being unhelpful.

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48868

Answer (score 3415):

### Did You Start `ssh-agent`?

You might need to start `ssh-agent` before you run the `ssh-add` command:

```bash
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
```

Note that this will start the agent for **msysgit Bash on Windows**. If you're using a different shell or operating system, you might need to use a variant of the command, such as those listed in the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20403535/456814).

See the following answers:

1. [ssh-add complains: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48863/ssh-add-complains-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/48868#48868)
2. [Git push requires username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password/18348125#18348125) (contains detailed instructions on how to use ssh-agent)
3. [How to run (git/ssh) authentication agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077302/456814).
4. [Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/17695338#17695338)

To automatically start ssh-agent and allow a single instance to work in multiple console windows, see [Start ssh-agent on login](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18915067/382458).

### Why do we need to use `eval` instead of just `ssh-agent`?

SSH needs two things in order to use ssh-agent: an ssh-agent instance running in the background, and an environment variable set that tells SSH which socket it should use to connect to the agent (SSH_AUTH_SOCK IIRC). If you just run ssh-agent then the agent will start, but SSH will have no idea where to find it.

from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/4086756#comment35753332_17848593).

### Public vs Private Keys

Also, whenever I use `ssh-add`, I always add private keys to it. The file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` looks like a public key, I'm not sure if that will work.  Do you have a `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file? If you open it in a text editor, does it say it's a private key?

Comment: Waaa? Why is this getting up-voted with the phrase 'always add private keys'? No offense Cupcake, but this flies in the face of the defined advantage of pub/priv keys: **"The critical advantage in an asymmetric key system is [...] never need to send a copy of their [private] keys to each other."** [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). I'm not saying it doesn't work, I'm just saying its like a vegan eating Risotto because that's what the recipe says--or whatever.

Comment: @xtian I'm not sure that I understand the issue. I don't know the exact details, but I'm guessing that the private key is never sent over the network. I think `ssh-add` merely decrypts an encrypted private key on the host machine, so that it can be used locally...it's ***never sent to anyone***. I'm guessing that only the public keys are ever sent over a network. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: You're too kind Cupcake. You're absolutely right. My bad. [ex here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys#ssh-agent); ssh-add adds the private key for the user's ssh-agent (running process) can act on the client/host's behalf with the server accepting rsa-whatever keys. Geez. I don't know what made me so excited.

Comment: @xtian getting ssh-add confused with ssh-copy-id?  After a several-month-long hiatus from Linux, I stumbled on this question while trying to find the latter....

Comment: @Ali may I ask what specifically you do not understand?

Comment: @cupcake I mean, what is the original problem that is being resolved here, it solved the problem what ever it was, but I want to understand how it works, thanks,

Comment: I'm curious why `eval ssh-agent -s` works, but `ssh-agent` on it's own doesn't.

Comment: @DanielM: SSH needs two things in order to use ssh-agent: an ssh-agent instance running in the background, and an environment variable set that tells SSH which socket it should use to connect to the agent (`SSH_AUTH_SOCK` IIRC). If you just run `ssh-agent` then the agent will start, but SSH will have no idea where to find it.

Comment: I had to `kill [PID]` my existing ssh-agent, and restart it like said in the answer. I located the current running ssh-agent with `ps | grep ssh-agent` on WindowsNT git bash

Comment: @Cupcake How come eval will set the SSH_AUTH_SOCK for you? Could I also start ssh-agent and set the environment variable manually?

Comment: @WeishiZeng sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for replying though. I just noticed that you used backquote in the command. I am so confused why the backquote (`) work for eval command but not single/double quote (', ") on my bash shell?

Comment: @WeishiZeng sorry, I don't know enough about Bash to explain why only backquotes work in this case either.

Comment: @WeishiZeng I know this is kind of late to answer, but it could help people.The command inside backquotes is executed in a new shell, and the output is sent to eval. If you execute ssh-agent, and copy/paste the output, then execute it, it will work as if you did use backquotes.

Comment: "'eval' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.". How to fix it? (Windows 7)

Comment: For an automated solution for CYGWIN BASH, check my [reply to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31309137/420996)

Comment: It might be useful to mention that "$(eval ssh-agent)" expires after a while (for me it was after I ended ssh session). Please indicate how to always launch ssh agent

Comment: Strangely `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` did not work, but `ssh-add` added the relevant directory anway

Comment: It could be a problem if gnome-keyring-daemon crashed. So, I found useful the http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32646/how-to-start-the-keyring-daemon-after-a-gnome-shell-crash article

Comment: does anyone know how to do this in powershell? when you try it in ps:
`eval : The term 'eval' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check`

Comment: If you are using git-bash on Windows check out the answer by Victor Alves below as his solution worked for me on Windows 10.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you. But I accidentally downvoted, if anyone edit this, I will be able to fix my vote (I will be grateful).

Comment: This worked like a charm. I've experienced the issue on a newly installed Linux distro.

Comment: It didn't work:

+ eval `ssh-agent -s`
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (eval:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: The answer by `Victor Alves` worked for me `eval $(ssh-agent)`

Answer (score 748):

I tried the other solutions to no avail. I made more research and found that the following command worked. I am using Windows 7 and [Git Bash](https://openhatch.org/missions/windows-setup/install-git-bash).

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

More information in: https://coderwall.com/p/rdi_wq ([web archive version](https://web.archive.org/web/20190612095943/https://coderwall.com/p/rdi_wq/fix-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent-when-using-ssh-add))

Comment: Worked on Windows 8 too.

Comment: I'm also using Windows 7 and Git Bash, and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17848593/456814) works just fine. It's cool that you can also do it this way too though.

Comment: Great !! Worked with windows 10 also.

Comment: Worked on Manjaro

Comment: $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
worked for me on Windows 10

Comment: Worked for me too. Don't understand it though.

Comment: thank you, worked like a charm!

depending on which console you are using, it might not know which socket to use to connect to the ssh agent service, eval seems to fix that for you by setting the environment variable for that console, at least how I understand it

Comment: ```eval $(ssh-agent)```

Worked for me on Windows 10. 

Then I just had to: ```ssh-add ~/.ssh/FILE_NAME```

Comment: Worked on Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: Worked on Windows 11.

Comment: Worked on Linux AWS box.

Answer (score 324):

The following command worked for me. I am using CentOS.

```
exec ssh-agent bash
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, I ran 'exec ssh-agent zsh' for my shell.

Comment: According to [this deleted "answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23115970/456814), it works on Amazon Linux AMI too. I guess it's a Unix/Linux/*nix solution.

Comment: I ssh'ed into a docker container and `ssh-add my.id_rsa` would fail on me. But `exec ssh-agent zsh` gave a environment where I could `ssh-add` with no problem. And I'm inside my docker container :)

Comment: Can anyone please briefly explain what the issue might have been? Thanks :)
This worked on my Ubuntu 14.04 too.

Comment: I did the same but ```exec ssh-agent fish```. None of the other solutions worked for me. This should be the accepted answer. I could not add my identity on Raspbian buster.

Comment: Worked on Win10 for me, probably not only a Unix solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: After all the searching this worked for me on Windows 10.

Comment: I tried this on ubuntu 22.04 and worked.
`eval "$(sudo ssh-agent -s)"` did not work and cause the error "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent"

Answer (score 281):

## Could not open a connection to your authentication agent

To resolve this error:

bash:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

tcsh:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -c`
```

Then use `ssh-add` as you normally would.

---

**Hot Tip:**

I was always forgetting what to type for the above ssh-agent commands, so I created an alias in my `.bashrc` file like this:

```
alias ssh-agent-cyg='eval `ssh-agent -s`'
```

Now instead of using `ssh-agent`, I can use `ssh-agent-cyg`

E.g.

```
$ ssh-agent-cyg
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-n16KsxjuTMiM/agent.32394; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=32395; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 32395;
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_pk
```

---

Original Source of fix:

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-10/msg00313.html

Comment: you will need to run the `eval` command every time you would have previously ran `ssh-agent`.  I use an alias now, see the updated answer for how I do this.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083079/ssh-agent-error-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Comment: I also needed to use the ssh specification instead of https (see https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/)

Comment: You sir, you are awesome. Thanks. ** I faced the same problem while cloning a bitbucket repo, I'd already setup an ssh key, but kept getting error: `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`.

Comment: Worked for me on windows 10 and git bash installed

Answer (score 237):

### MsysGit or Cygwin

If you're using Msysgit or Cygwin you can find a good tutorial at [SSH-Agent in msysgit and cygwin and bash](http://anterence.blogspot.com/2012/01/ssh-agent-in-msysgit.html):

1. Add a file called `.bashrc` to your home folder.
2. Open the file and paste in:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   eval `ssh-agent -s`
   ssh-add
   ```
3. This assumes that your key is in the conventional `~/.ssh/id_rsa` location. If it isn't, include a full path after the `ssh-add` command.
4. Add to or create file `~/.ssh/config` with the contents

   ```
   ForwardAgent yes
   ```

   In the original tutorial the `ForwardAgent` param is `Yes`, but it's a typo. Use all lowercase or you'll get errors.
5. Restart Msysgit. It will ask you to enter your passphrase once, and that's it (until you end the session, or your ssh-agent is killed.)

### Mac/OS X

If you don't want to start a new ssh-agent every time you open a terminal, check out [Keychain](https://github.com/funtoo/keychain). I'm on a Mac now, so I used the tutorial [*ssh-agent with zsh & keychain on Mac OS X*](http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/ssh-agent-with-zsh-keychain-on-mac-os-x/) to set it up, but I'm sure a Google search will have plenty of info for Windows.

**Update**: A better solution on Mac is to add your key to the Mac OS Keychain:

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Simple as that.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083079/ssh-agent-error-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Comment: When I do `eval \`ssh-agent -s\`` the process does not stop when I exit cygwin.

Comment: Is there a way to setup the config for Windows / gitbash so you dont have to do it every time?

Comment: It should be `ps -u $(whoami) | grep ssh-agent &> /dev/null || eval $(ssh-agent)` - otherwise a new ssh-agent is started everytime. Killed my machine every now and then when user had cronjobs.

Comment: @shredding, if that command is universal, feel free to edit my answer and add it in the appropriate place.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` somehow wasn't evaluated in my Cygwin environment (maybe because of http://stackoverflow.com/a/18393620/923560 ). Instead I added the two statements from step 2 to `~/.profile`, which works well.

Comment: `ForwardAgent yes` isn't necessary and is a [nontheoretical security risk](https://heipei.github.io/2015/02/26/SSH-Agent-Forwarding-considered-harmful/) if it's set for any untrusted server. Local access to your key-agent should function regardless of this setting.

Comment: **Unknown option --K**

Comment: The solution provided for MsysGit and Cygwin also works for the git bash emulation that is part of the git installation on Windows 7. The usage of eval is important.

Comment: Didn't happen before, but this wasn't working this time, refused connection.  Only had SSH_AUTH_SOCK.  Started agent manually, transformed variables to work with fish, then it worked again =/.

Comment: After last MacOS update, you should use `-k` not a capital letter

Answer (score 225):

Run

```
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add
```

To get more details you can search

```
ssh-agent
```

or run

```
man ssh-agent
```

Comment: I would recommend that If you are working with git bash on windows then try this.

Comment: @neer17 this allowed me to use `ssh-copy-id` on ubuntu. Unsure why I couldn't add the key without using `ssh-agent` to launch bash.

Comment: This is the one for Windows! (tested on W10pro build 1809 and git 2.21.0)

Comment: I am using ZSH and this works for me: `ssh-agent zsh; ssh-add`

Comment: My Cygwin and Git Bash were working fine, but for some reason the Console opened from the Fork client didn't work, and this fixed it. I'll probably just use Git Bash in the future, but at least I know how to get it to work now :)

Comment: This helped me on Manjaro. Thanks!

Answer (score 139):

ssh-add and ssh (assuming you are using the openssh implementations) require an environment variable to know how to talk to the ssh agent. If you started the agent in a different command prompt window to the one you're using now, or if you started it incorrectly, neither ssh-add nor ssh will see that environment variable set (because the environment variable is set *locally* to the command prompt it's set in).

You don't say which version of ssh you're using, but if you're using cygwin's, you can use this recipe from [*SSH Agent on Cygwin*](https://killtheradio.net/how-tos/ssh-agent-on-cygwin/):

```bash
# Add to your Bash config file
SSHAGENT=/usr/bin/ssh-agent
SSHAGENTARGS="-s"
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" -a -x "$SSHAGENT" ]; then
    eval `$SSHAGENT $SSHAGENTARGS`
    trap "kill $SSH_AGENT_PID" 0
fi
```

This will start an agent automatically for each new command prompt window that you open (which is suboptimal if you open multiple command prompts in one session, but at least it should work).

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083079/ssh-agent-error-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Comment: I was linked here from another SO question.  Can I ask why it's necessary to add this to the Bash config file?  On my machine all I need to do is run `eval $(ssh-agent)` and I can use password-less ssh for every new terminal window.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible, unless you're launching new terminals from that terminal.

Comment: Can you outline what this piece of code does? People who don't get the answer by themselves (such as me) won't know what this actually does.

Comment: @shuhalo I literally wrote underneath the code what it does.

Answer (score 135):

I faced the same problem for Linux, and here is what I did:

Basically, the command ssh-agent starts the agent, but it doesn't really set the environment variables for it to run. It just outputs those variables to the shell.

You need to:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

and then do ssh-add. See *[Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](http://funkaoshi.com/blog/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent)*.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083079/ssh-agent-error-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Comment: Worked for me too while having problem using boot2docker on Windows.

Comment: This was what it took for me.

Answer (score 119):

Instead of using `ssh-agent -s`, I used `` eval `ssh-agent -s` ``  to solve this issue.

Here is what I performed step by step (step 2 onwards on [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway)):

1. Cleaned up my *.ssh* folder at `C:\user\<username>\.ssh\`
2. Generated a new SSH key:
   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "xyz@abc.com"`
3. Check if any process id(ssh agent) is already running.
   `ps aux | grep ssh`
4. (Optional) If found any in step 3, kill those
   `kill <pids>`
5. Started the SSH agent
   `` $ eval `ssh-agent -s` ``
6. Added SSH key generated in step 2 to the SSH agent
   `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: 'eval' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You can just restart agent by eval `ssh-agent -s` and add older key using ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa. If you generate new SSH key then you will need to update that key in all your services such as github, bitbucket, etc.

Comment: Is there a way make this survive Windows restarts? After the restart it don't work until I launch "eval `ssh-agent -s`" and "ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa" again.

Comment: after searching for a long time, this is the solution that worked

Answer (score 113):

Try to do the following steps:

1. Open [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) and run: `cd ~/.ssh`
2. Try to run agent: `eval $(ssh-agent)`
3. Right now, you can run the following command: `ssh-add -l`

Comment: This is the only solution here that worked for me (on windows 7). First I used the `ps aux | grep ssh` and the `kill` command in Rick's answer to kill the agents. After that `ssh-add` worked without the -l switch (Using -l gave an error). `eval 'ssh-agent'` as in Rick's answer did not work, I had to use `eval $(ssh-agent)` like in Chechoro's answer here.

Comment: +1 I had the exact same problem as OP (Windows 7) and this is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083079/ssh-agent-error-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Comment: @Frug It is backticks, not apostrophes; in shell script that means to execute what's contained inside. `$(ssh-agent)` is equivalent to `\`ssh-agent\`` but more readable.

Comment: I had the same issue in Ubuntu 21.10 and the above solution worked; when simply running `ssh-agent` didn't, but why? Why have to use `eval`?

Answer (score 62):

In Windows 10 I tried all answers listed here, but none of them seemed to work. In fact, they give a clue. To solve a problem, simply you need three commands. **The idea of this problem is that ssh-add needs the SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AGENT_PID environment variables to be set with the current ssh-agent sock file path and pid number.**

```
ssh-agent -s > temp.txt
```

This will save the output of ssh-agent in a file. The text file content will be something like this:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-kjmxRb2764/agent.2764; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=3044; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 3044;
```

Copy something like "/tmp/ssh-kjmxRb2764/agent.2764" from the text file and run the following command directly in the console:

```
set SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-kjmxRb2764/agent.2764
```

Copy something like "3044" from the text file and run the following command directly in the console:

```
set SSH_AGENT_PID=3044
```

Now when environment variables (SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AGENT_PID) are set for the current console session, run your ssh-add command and it will not fail again to connect to ssh agent.

Comment: These steps are the same as doing 'eval $(ssh-agent)'

Comment: Thank you for explaining exactly what's going on, instead of just throwing bash commands at the answer.

Comment: WOW, what a journey . . . Thank you so much.  I would add one comment for Jaskey or others where it seemed to fail.  The environment variables need to be set in any session where you are using git.exe . . . NOT JUST ssh-add.  In short, to use this solution, once you get ssh-agent running and ssh-add done, you need to make sure those environment variables are set in any terminal session where you want to use git.exe.  In my case, I got ssh-add to work finally and but then git.exe failed . . . it was only then that I "saw the light" about the "terminal session" comments.

Comment: This actually helped me to save the issue on Linux...just needed to replace `set` by `export`

Comment: Absolutely inspired me. To simplify, just run `. temp.txt` which recovers the agent

Answer (score 39):

One thing I came across was that `eval` did not work for me using Cygwin, what worked for me was `ssh-agent ssh-add id_rsa`.

After that I came across an issue that my private key was too open, the solution I managed to find for that (from [here](http://www.tiv.net/2013/12/cygwin-id-rsa-too-open.html)):

```
chgrp Users id_rsa
```

as well as

```
chmod 600 id_rsa
```

finally I was able to use:

```
ssh-agent ssh-add id_rsa
```

Comment: Did you use `eval \`ssh-agent\``, with the backticks `\`` around `ssh-agent`, as shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17848593/456814)? That worked just fine for me in Cygwin. You seem to be right that `ssh-agent ssh-add` also works though, at least in the msysgit Bash. However, note that `id_rsa` is the default key that's used, so you don't need to specify it with `ssh-agent ssh-add id_rsa`.

Comment: I believe I had used the backticks, but for me still no dice

Comment: OMG YOU SOLVED MY FEW HOURS FRUSTATION. Thanks!

Answer (score 36):

For Windows users, I found cmd `` eval `ssh-agent -s` ``  didn't work, but using [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) worked a treat:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`; ssh-add KEY_LOCATION
```

And making sure the Windows service "OpenSSH Key Management" wasn't disabled.

Comment: Could you please tell why do we need `eval` at all?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Execute `ssh-agent` by itself and you'll see why. It produces commands that need to be `eval`uated, otherwise they aren't executed.

Comment: @amzon-ex I tried that, but I did not understand the behavior, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Running just `ssh-agent` produces some text in a string form which if you typed by yourself in the terminal, they would act as commands or variable assignments. `eval` does the job of taking the string and converting them to actual runnable commands.

Answer (score 28):

To amplify on [n3o's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/17739213#17739213) for Windows 7...

My problem was indeed that some required environment variables weren't set, and n3o is correct that ssh-agent tells you how to set those environment variables, but doesn't actually set them.

Since Windows doesn't let you do "eval," here's what to do instead:

Redirect the output of ssh-agent to a batch file with

```
ssh-agent > temp.bat
```

Now use a text editor such as Notepad to edit temp.bat. For each of the first two lines:

- Insert the word "set" and a space at the beginning of the line.
- Delete the first semicolon and everything that follows.

Now delete the third line. Your temp.bat should look something like this:

```
set SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-EorQv10636/agent.10636
set SSH_AGENT_PID=8608
```

Run *temp.bat*. This will set the environment variables that are needed for ssh-add to work.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083079/ssh-agent-error-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Comment: I still get `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` when running ssh-add in Win10 PowerShell.

Answer (score 23):

I just got this working.  Open your `~/.ssh/config` file.

Append the following-

```
Host github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
```

The page that gave me the hint [Set up SSH for Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git)
said that the single space indentation is important... though I had a configuration in here from Heroku that did not have that space and works properly.

Comment: This does not help with entering the passphrase for the SSH key.

Comment: If you don't want to enter the passphrase, create a key without one.  There is no point in having a passphrase if you're just going to store it in your script anyway.

Comment: That is the whole point of using ssh-agent. The password to your keys is stored in a secure keychain, handled by ssh-agent.

Comment: This is the best answer for me here. Had lots of problems with ssh-agent starting thousands of times in Windows 7 and that kill trap didn't do the trick. I don't mind having no passphrase on my personal computer at home.

Answer (score 20):

If you follow these instructions, your problem would be solved.

If you’re on a Mac or Linux machine, type:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

If you’re on a Windows machine, type:

```
ssh-agent -s
```

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) and the other solutions didn't help me.

I finally realized what my problem was. I had created my SSH keys in the `/root/.ssh` folder, so even when I ran `ssh-add` as root, it couldn't do its work and kept saying:

> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

I created my SSH public and private keys in `/home/myUsername/` folder and I used

```
ssh-agent /bin/sh
```

Then I ran

```
ssh-add /home/myUsername/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And problem was solved this way.

**Note:** For accessing your repository in Git, add your Git password when you are creating SSH keys with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your Git email here"`.

Answer (score 17):

## You need to start the ssh agent

In your terminal, run:

`eval $(ssh-agent -s)`

Answer (score 16):

Let me offer another solution.  If you have just installed Git 1.8.2.2 or thereabouts, and you want to enable SSH, follow the well-writen [directions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git).

Everything through to Step 5.6 where you might encounter a slight snag.  If an SSH agent is already be running you could get the following error message when you restart bash

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent
```

If you do, use the following command to see if more than one ssh-agent process is running

```
ps aux | grep ssh
```

If you see more than one ssh-agent service, you will need to kill all of these processes.  Use the kill command as follows (the PID will be unique on your computer)

```
kill <PID>
```

Example:

```
kill 1074
```

After you have removed all of the ssh-agent processes, run the *px aux | grep ssh* command again to be sure they are gone, then restart Bash.

Voila, you should now get something like this:

```
Initializing new SSH agent...
succeeded
Enter passphrase for /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

Now you can continue on Step 5.7 and beyond.

Comment: got me passed roadblock, tyvm

Comment: Just wanted to add that in my case one of the items listed is the grep process that we are doing the searching with, but it is already killed after its execution. No pun intended.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083079/ssh-agent-error-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Answer (score 15):

This will run the SSH agent and authenticate *only the first time you need it*, not every time you open your Bash terminal. It can be used for any program using SSH in general, including `ssh` itself and [`scp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy). Just add this to `/etc/profile.d/ssh-helper.sh`:

```bash
ssh-auth() {
    # Start the SSH agent only if not running
    [[ -z $(ps | grep ssh-agent) ]] && echo $(ssh-agent) > /tmp/ssh-agent-data.sh

    # Identify the running SSH agent
    [[ -z $SSH_AGENT_PID ]] && source /tmp/ssh-agent-data.sh > /dev/null

    # Authenticate (change key path or make a symlink if needed)
    [[ -z $(ssh-add -l | grep "/home/$(whoami)/.ssh/id_rsa") ]] && ssh-add
}

# You can repeat this for other commands using SSH
git() { ssh-auth; command git "$@"; }
```

> ***Note:** this is an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4083079/1726010), which has been merged with this one.
> That question was for Windows 7, meaning my answer was for Cygwin/MSYS/MSYS2. This one seems for some Unix, where I wouldn't expect the SSH agent needing to be managed like this*.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083079/ssh-agent-error-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Comment: ssh-agent process do not seems to be associated with the same terminal used to run it. I guess `ps -A | grep ssh-agent` or `ps h -C ssh-agent` should be used instead of `ps | grep ssh-agent`

Comment: Using a hyphen in the function name might not be recommended. I don't know why, but read [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/gotchas.html). For instance, I found that `echo ssh-auth | bash` will fail.

Comment: You can simplyfy this a bit more. Just check whether it is running and assign the env variables. And then add `AddKeysToAgent yes` (or use `prompt`) to your ssh config entry (use `Host *` for all Hosts.) That way you will only be asked for the SSH password if you actually try to connect otherwise you might be asked for a password for a simple `git diff` or `git status`.

Comment: `$HOME/.ssh` might be more robust than `/home/$(whoami)/.ssh`

Comment: I added this to my `.zprofile`, because the scripts in `profile.d` were are not sourced for zsh. I have a question: why do effectively check twice if the `ssh-agent` is running or not? I mean, both `ps -A | grep ssh-agent` and `$SSH_AGENT_PID` are used to check if an ssh-agent already exists, right?

Answer (score 12):

The basic solution to run `ssh-agent` is answered in many answers. However runing `ssh-agent` many times (per each opened terminal or per remote login) will create a many copies ot `ssh-agent` running in memory. The scripts which is suggested to avoid that problem is long and need to write and/or copy separated file or need to write too many strings in `~/.profile` or `~/.schrc`. Let me suggest **simple two string solution:**

For **sh**, **bash**, etc:

```sh
# ~/.profile
if ! pgrep -q -U `whoami` -x 'ssh-agent'; then ssh-agent -s > ~/.ssh-agent.sh; fi
. ~/.ssh-agent.sh
```

For **csh**, **tcsh**, etc:

```sh
# ~/.schrc
sh -c 'if ! pgrep -q -U `whoami` -x 'ssh-agent'; then ssh-agent -c > ~/.ssh-agent.tcsh; fi'
eval `cat ~/.ssh-agent.tcsh`
```

What is here:

- search the process `ssh-agent` by name and by current user
- create appropriate shell script file by calling `ssh-agent` and run `ssh-agent` itself if no current user `ssh-agent` process found
- evaluate created shell script which configure appropriate environment

It is not necessary to protect created shell script `~/.ssh-agent.tcsh` or `~/.ssh-agent.sh` from another users access because: at-first communication with `ssh-agent` is processed through protected socket which is not accessible to another users, and at-second another users can found `ssh-agent` socket simple by enumeration files in `/tmp/` directory. As far as about access to `ssh-agent` process it is the same things.

Answer (score 12):

In Windows 10, using the **Command Prompt** terminal, the following works for me:

```
ssh-agent cmd 
ssh-add
```

You should then be asked for a passphrase after this:

```
Enter passphrase for /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

Comment: For non-Windows users: `ssh-agent bash` or `ssh-agent zsh` might be the solution.

Comment: Thank you, living in Windows is sure frustating.

Answer (score 10):

Try the following:

```
ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add && git push heroku master'
```

Comment: Looks like a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 10):

Use parameter -A when you connect to server, example:

```
ssh -A root@myhost
```

from man page :

```
-A Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.  
   This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.

   Agent forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the agent's
   UNIX-domain socket) can access the local agent through the forwarded 
   connection.  An attacker cannot obtain key material from the agent,
   however they can perform operations on the keys that enable them to
   authenticate using the identities loaded into the agent.
```

Comment: What does it do and why?

Comment: as per man page ... man ssh ...      -A      Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.  This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem, when I started ssh-agent, when it was already running.  It seems that the multiple instances conflict with each other.

To see if ssh-agent is already running, check the value of the SSH_AGENT_SOCK environment variable with:

```
echo $SSH_AGENT_SOCK
```

If it is set, then the agent is presumably running.

To check if you have more than one ssh-agent running, you can review:

```
ps -ef | grep ssh
```

Of course, then you should kill any additional instances that you created.

Comment: I think running `eval $(ssh-agent)` is supposed to create a new agent with a different PID every time, though I could be wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "Gets confused"? E.g., what or who gets confused? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24570230/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: just to add, in order to kill a process use this command `kill <process_id> pid`

Comment: Is this answer really supposed to say `SSH_AGENT_SOCK`? When I run `ssh-agent`, I see it setting environment variables named `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID`, but nothing named `SSH_AGENT_SOCK`.

Answer (score 7):

Read [user456814's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17848593/420996) for explanations. Here I only try to automate the fix.

If you using a [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) terminal with Bash, add the following to the *$HOME/.bashrc* file. This only starts *ssh-agent* once in the first Bash terminal and adds the keys to *ssh-agent*. (I am not sure if this is required on Linux.)

```
###########################
# start ssh-agent for
# ssh authentication with github.com
###########################
SSH_AUTH_SOCK_FILE=/tmp/SSH_AUTH_SOCK.sh
if [ ! -e $SSH_AUTH_SOCK_FILE ]; then
    # need to find SSH_AUTH_SOCK again.
    # restarting is an easy option
    pkill ssh-agent
fi
# check if already running
SSH_AGENT_PID=`pgrep ssh-agent`
if [ "x$SSH_AGENT_PID" == "x" ]; then
#   echo "not running. starting"
    eval $(ssh-agent -s) > /dev/null
    rm -f $SSH_AUTH_SOCK_FILE
    echo "export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" > $SSH_AUTH_SOCK_FILE
    ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/github.com_id_rsa 2>&1 > /dev/null
#else
#   echo "already running"
fi
source $SSH_AUTH_SOCK_FILE
```

*Don’t forget* to add your correct keys in the "ssh-add" command.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to get this to work on Windows to connect to the stash via SSH.

Here is the solution that worked for me.

1. Turns out I was running the Pageant ssh agent on my Windows box - I would check what you are running. I suspect it is Pageant as it comes as default with PuTTY and WinSCP.
2. The ssh-add does not work from command line with this type of agent
3. You need to add the private key via the Pageant UI window which you can get by double-clicking the Pageant icon in the taskbar (once it is started).
4. Before you add the key to Pageant you need to convert it to *PPK* format. Full instructions are available here [How to convert SSH key to ppk format](http://kb.site5.com/shell-access-ssh/how-to-convert-ssh-keys-to-ppk-format/)
5. That is it. Once I uploaded my key to stash I was able to use Sourcetree to create a local repository and clone the remote.

Answer (score 5):

Using [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) on [Windows 8.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8.1) E, my resolution was as follows:

```
eval $(ssh-agent) > /dev/null
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to output to `/dev/null`? Your answer basically does the exact same thing as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21909432/456814).

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is the default key, so you shouldn't have to specify `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, just `ssh-add` should work.

Comment: I tried your solution in this same environment @Cupcake, it doesn't work.  I don't get why this is the answer either, but unless I did it this way it never worked.

Comment: @user456814 The `> /dev/null` is widely used, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent. I guess it is not really necessary. `The output redirect just gets rid of the printed "Agent pid blah blah".`, see http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/12/understanding-ssh-agent-and-ssh-add/.

Comment: What is "E" after Windows 8.1? A particular edition of Windows 8.1? Or something else?

Answer (score 5):

For Bash built into Windows 10, I added this to file *[.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)*:

```
if [ -z $SSH_AUTH_SOCK ]; then
    if [ -r ~/.ssh/env ]; then
            source ~/.ssh/env
            if [ `ps -p $SSH_AGENT_PID | wc -l` = 1 ]; then
                    rm ~/.ssh/env
                    unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK
            fi
    fi
fi

if [ -z $SSH_AUTH_SOCK ]; then
    ssh-agent -s | sed 's/^echo/#echo/'> ~/.ssh/env
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/env
    source ~/.ssh/env > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

Comment: I don't know why you paste so much text if you could've just said to call `$(ssh-agent -s)` to set the agent's environment.

Comment: This worked for me when I used it the first time. But after a system reboot, it actually caused the issue to be worse. With ssh not working _at all_ anymore. Not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved the error by force stopping (killed) git processes (ssh agent), then uninstalling Git, and then installing Git again.

Comment: I suspect that all you needed to do was just kill any existing agent processes, then restart one, instead of having to reinstall Git.

Answer (score 4):

An "agent forwarding" is a tecnhique that could help you out. This makes the local SSH keys "available" during the active session within the server.

If you are using PuTTY on Windows, you need to set the "Connection/SSH/Auth/Allow agent forwarding" option to "true".

[image]

Comment: Why? Why is it necessary? What is the theory of operation? Please respond by [changing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28055546/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 4):

This [worked](https://imikay.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/ssh-add-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent-on-windows/) for me.

> In the CMD window, type the following command:

```
cd path-to-Git/bin # (for example,cd C:\Program Files\Git\bin)
bash
exec ssh-agent bash
ssh-add path/to/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: I've got it working like this in cmd as well but still get the error in git bash.. I don't understand. How could I make it work in git bash as well?

Answer (score 2):

Also check your remote URL. Use *git@github...* instead of the *https://* protocol.

See *[GitExtensions and PuTTY via SSH on a custom port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300647/gitextensions-putty-via-ssh-on-custom-port/33928364#33928364)*.

Answer (score 2):

### For PowerShell in Windows

I was having trouble with PowerShell and the `Start-SshAgent` / `Add-SshKey` commands, so I whipped up a quick script that might help some folks out. This is intended to be added to your PowerShell profile which you can edit by executing `notepad $PROFILE`:

```
if ($(Get-Process ssh-agent) -eq $null)
{
     $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($(ssh-agent -c).Replace("setenv", "set"));
}
```

It will detect if the `ssh-agent` is running or not and only execute if there is no agent running already. Please note that `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString` is a pretty dangerous command, so you may not want to use this solution if you are using an untrusted copy of `ssh-agent`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you typed '**eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"**' not ' **eval "ssh-agent -s"**'

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with when using `PowerShell`.

Add the below function to your `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

```
function RunSsh($userIdentity ) {
   $agent=ssh-agent
   $position=$agent[0].IndexOf("=")
   $ending=$agent[0].IndexOf(";")

   $variableStartPosition=$agent[0].IndexOf("export")
   $variableEndPosition=$agent[0].LastIndexOf(";")
   $variableName=$agent[0].Substring($variableStartPosition+7,$variableEndPosition-$variableStartPosition-7)
   [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($variableName, $agent[0].Substring($position+1,$ending-$position-1))

   $position=$agent[1].IndexOf("=")
   $ending=$agent[1].IndexOf(";")

   $variableStartPosition=$agent[1].IndexOf("export")
   $variableEndPosition=$agent[1].LastIndexOf(";")
   $variableName=$agent[1].Substring($variableStartPosition+7,$variableEndPosition-$variableStartPosition-7)
   [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($variableName, $agent[1].Substring($position+1,$ending-$position-1))

   if($userIdentity.Length -eq 0) {
      ssh-add
   } else {
      ssh-add $userIdentity
   }
}
```

Now from the command line you can run `RunSsh` which uses identity file in `~\.ssh` folder or pass in the identity file with `RunSsh C:\ssh\id_rsa` where `C:\ssh\id_rsa` is your identity file.

For this to work you need to have `ssh-add` and `ssh-agent` in your `path` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was getting "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." on running the command while generating and adding SSH key: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

I resolved it by stopping the multiple `ssh-agent` instances running on my machine and then uninstalled the Git from control panel on my Windows machine and then again installed Git and things were working now.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083079/ssh-agent-error-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my [Comodo firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comodo_Internet_Security#Features) had sandboxed the ssh agent. Once I disabled sandboxing I was able to clone the repository.

FYI, I am using Comodo firewall on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Quite an important and silly mistake I made - not generating the key in ~/.ssh folder.
Before starting all the steps described on github, change into ~/.ssh. That solved my problem

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Answer (score 0):

If you anyway get this error, try change .ssh/config to something like this:

Host *
ForwardAgent yes
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

I before do it, specify user and address, but it's no work, after I change it to this variant, it's work!

Answer (score -1):

Create config file in ~/.ssh and set PERMANENTLY, host can be  ip/domain
it wast test in windows10

```
Host 20.16.4.5
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_ec2
```

if you want to past .pem to pub. using in aws
1 Copy private key in PEM to .ssh folder

```
$ cp /path/to/my-aws-ec2-instance.pem ~/.ssh/id_rsa_ec2
```

2 Generate and save public key

```
 ssh-keygen -y -f /path/to/my-aws-ec2-instance.pem > ~/.ssh/id_rsa_ec2.pub
```

AND  SET (MANUAL add your key to the agent PERMANENTLY ), AND THEN use ec2 without pem
ssh ec2-user@ec2-ip.compute-x.amazonaws.com

Answer (score -1):

There's a possibility that this solution will work for you Try once

In my case, it was related to DNS mapping (bitbucket was not pointing to the correct IP) I fixed it by doing a simple trick (i overwritten the IP address to point when looking for bitbucket.org)

open and edit /etc/hosts in ubuntu (in case of any other OS please look how can you can do the same)

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

and add the following line (in the case of GitHub or any other website look for the IP and do the mapping accordingly)

```
18.205.93.2 bitbucket.org
```

and then it'll resolve the issue

Answer (score -2):

I had this error when trying to download a Git repository:

> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent. ssh-add exit code 2

To get rid of this error:

**You need neither `ssh-agent` nor `ssh-add`** when you use a ***passwordless*** private key. See *[Add private key to ssh-agent in docker file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48290333/11154841)*.

A passwordless private key does not need to make the system insecure if you treat it right (delete it after usage). Perhaps this helps at this [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) problem as well?

---

When should this "trick" be most relevant? In a Dockerfile!

- I had to use a passwordless private key to get a Dockerfile to clone a Git repository since you cannot enter a password in the shell during the Dockerfile run. See [Dockerfile: clone repo with passwordless private key. Errors: “authentication agent” or “read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty”](https://superuser.com/questions/1633085/dockerfile-clone-repo-with-passwordless-private-key-errors-authentication-ag) as an example.
- More recently, also consider deployment tokens to access a Git repository without manual password entry.

Comment: Passwordless private keys are dangerous. If your computer is compromised, so are all your accounts that accept connections using those keys.

Comment: @AlexisWilke "A passwordless private key does not need to make the system insecure if you treat it right (delete it after usage)." If you want to use a private key in a Dockerfile, you *must* use a passwordless key to avoid entering the password in the terminal during the run. You can also delete the key that is dropped inside the layers of the Docker image by copying only the last layer of the image that used the key to a new image, see [option 2 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66648529/11154841). Or use deployment tokens, which is also mentioned in the answer here.