# could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

Tags: git, github, docker

I'm using `git` to build a `docker` image with this command: `sudo docker build github.com/roseperrone/myproject`, but I get this error:

`could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address`

How should I provide my git credentials?

I'm running inside an AWS ec2 instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886729/fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-no-such-device-or-addre)

Answer (score 5):

To understand this error, it helps to recall that there are two ways to check out code from Github: with user name/password, and authenticating with an SSH key.

In the Github UI, the "Clone or download" button offers two options: *Clone with SSH* and *Use HTTPS*. (You might only get both options if you have added SSH keys to your Github account, I don't know). Checking out code using the https-URL requires typing your user name and password to authenticate. The SSH option creates a git@github - URL and checking out does not ask for user name and password.

I would recommend that you do *not* save your Github account password on the EC2 machine or in the Docker configuration. Neither would I recommend that you copy your personal id_rsa file onto the EC2 instance. Instead, [create a dedicated SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) for this purpose on Github. Give it a suitable label and decide if you want to allow pushing code or just pulling. This means you can easily revoke access later should the key get lost or if you stop using this setup.

More info about how to use the generated SSH key in the Docker setup can be found in this question:
[Using SSH keys inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136389/using-ssh-keys-inside-docker-container)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I recently joined github but this bug is annoying me so much.
I have sucessfully fixed it,

First of all [Generate an SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) and authenticate it.

Remove any previous remote address if it doesn't work, now go to your repositiory and copy the ssh clone url.

now open type the following command :

> git remote add origin git@github.com:username/your-repo.git

replace **username** and **your-repo** with your username and repo.
now try to push your changes, run the following command.

> git push origin master

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, it doesn't look like there's an option to provide credentials, so instead I copied my `id_rsa` key, ran `git clone`, `cd`d into it, and ran `docker build .`

Answer (score -2):

When push try to force it with:

```
$ git push -u -f origin <name_of_branch>
```

I know it's a bit strange, but it works for me...

Answer (score -4):

I think you need to set the git config via the command line.

See the github setup documentation: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-all

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
$ git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

Etc.

Answer (score -5):

In case anyone else comes across this question and needs help, in your Dockerfile clone your repo with your credentials by issuing the following command:

```
git clone https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/project.git
```

Make sure your password is encoded.

Comment: Although this might work you should never ever paste your password into a random website.