# Fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, github, capistrano

I have been deploying my Rails 4 application to Rackspace using github and capistrano for a few weeks now.  Everything worked fine until I finally made my repository private.  Now, I am receiving the following error after running 'cap deploy':

"fatal: could not read Password for 'https://username@github.com': No such device or address"

Below is the code from my deploy.rb file

```
set :application, "appname"
set :repository,  "https://git_username@github.com/git_username/appname.git"
set :scm, :git
set :scm_username, "git_username"
set :scm_passphrase, "git_password"
set :scm_command, "git"
set :keep_releases, 5
set :branch, "master"
set :rails_env, "production"

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/doLocal"

set :user, "deployer"
set :password, "deployer_password"
set :use_sudo, false

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

server "/path/to/server", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"


namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

I have tried it with and without the username prepended to the github repository name.  If it is there, I receive the password error from above, but if it is not there, I receive the following error:

"fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address"

Any idea what the issue is?  I'm assuming it has something to do with me changing to a private repository.  I have read some things about using ssh but have also read not to.

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you try and specify the user in the https url: `https://user@github.com/username/repo.git`

Comment: I tried doing that but then got the same error except that the Password could not be read

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So, I figured it out.  In order to use a private repo on Github to deploy using https, you need to use Github's OAuth API.  Under Edit Profile on your github account, click applications and then generate an OAuth Token.  Then, prepend your token to your repo url like so:

```
 set :repository,  "https://<OAuthToken>@github.com/username/application.git"
```

After that, I was able to run

```
 cap deploy
```

and deploy my application to my remote server.

Comment: Is this a secure method of doing this having the OAuthToken in a file on the server? Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

The error message is a generic git error, though the question itself is Ruby specific.

So for anyone else that landed here, here's a **non-rails answer**: the missing device is actually a console.

1. You've tried to authenticate non-interactively (ie, using an SSH key). This has failed.
2. As a fallback, git has tried to prompt the user to input a username, but this doesn't work as an interactive console is not available.

Fix #1, since you probably don't want to authenticate interactively during a deploy. In my case it was a github oauth issue.

Answer (score 0):

`fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address"`

check the `github` `username` first  Also your `scm user` is same as server `user` in your code?

Your code

```
 set :scm_user, "user"
 set :user, "user"
```

It should be

```
 set :user, "deployer"  # The server's user for deploys
 set :scm_user, "ram"  # The   github username
```

also set the passphrase

```
  set :scm_passphrase, "p@ssw0rd"  # The deploy user's password
```

Now repository case..As per I think you repository setting should be

```
set :repository, "git@github.com:username/repo.git"  # Your clone URL
```

Also

```
 set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried all of those, but it did not work.  I did not have the username set up correctly as you clarified above, but changing the repository resulted in capistrano not being able to find the repository and it said 'Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.'