# Error when push commits with Github: fatal: could not read Username

Tags: git, github

Since few time, I use Github for my projects and I have an issue when I want to push commits.

To beginning, I have forked a repository. Then I have cloned the fork (with command line `git clone https://github.com/ ...`) and, after doing modifications, I have committed with success (`git commit -a`).

After this, I have tried to push commits with command line `git push` but I obtain the following error:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory
```

Have you got an idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19012466/354577) on [Fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18886729/354577).

Comment: @Chris: no it's a bug in 1.8.5

Answer (score 63, accepted):

What I had to do was:

`git remote rm origin`
`git remote add origin 'git@github.com:username/repo.git'`

Then, I was able to push my changes.

Comment: What is `the_git@link` ?

Comment: Sorry @Mr_and_Mrs_D, I just saw your comment today. What I meant by `the_git@link` was the SSH clone URL, instead of the HTTPS clone URL.

Comment: what about when you dont want to use ssh keys?

Comment: you can also use
git remote set-url origin 'git@github.com:username/repo.git'

Comment: What causes the origin to get messed up? This fixed things for me but I didn't understand what broke it.

Comment: @CrisAbrams It's caused by a bug in git 1.8.5 (take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20884273/2241993)). Updating to a newer version seems to solve the problem too.

Comment: I think when you say "username/repo.git" in fact you mean "organization/repo.git." Correct?

Answer (score 24):

I tried following command and it worked for me

```
git push https://<username>:<password>@github.com/<username>/<repository-name>
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, exposing your password like that.

Answer (score 22):

Well I had the same problem - what annoys me to no end is that *I don't have a clue why* (edit: bug). I was pushing with `https`. Manually editing the config did not work for me (or doing a chkdsk as suggested in another answer). I ended up pushing with ssh - as in, replace:

```
https://github.com/USER/REPO.git
```

with

```
git@github.com:USER/REPO.git
```

after [generating your keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

**EDIT** as to why : it is a bug in 1.8.5. See [the report](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/153) and a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/msysgit/s4dB8Nv9V4c/55-cGPdPYmAJ) with a way to workaround

Answer (score 16):

Since it's a bug from 1.8.5 version, if you don't want use SSH Key you can downgrade to 1.84 from [here](https://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/Git-1.8.4-preview20130916.exe), or upgrade to higher version, 1.9.x, for example.

Answer (score 11):

This seems to be a known bug in Git 1.8.5 on Windows. As described and reported by @Mr_and_Mrs_D:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/msysgit/s4dB8Nv9V4c/55-cGPdPYmAJ

Downgrading to 1.8.4 works for me. Please note you have to explicitly uninstall 1.8.5 first by running `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\unins000.exe` as described here:

https://github.com/swcarpentry/bc/issues/234#issuecomment-33055444

I downloaded 1.8.4 here:
https://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/Git-1.8.4-preview20130916.exe

Comment: I've created an [unofficial fix release (1.8.5.4)](https://github.com/nevik/git/releases/tag/v1.8.5.4.msysgit.nevik.0) for people who want to or need to use a Git version newer than 1.8.4. This should serve as an intermediate solution until a new official release is made.

Comment: Quite disappointing, if the notoriously most basic use case: git clone... + git add... + git commit + git push does not work. None of the hints in the answers above worked for me, but the final workaround was to use git gui, which did the work immediately. It asked for username and password, and performed push as expected. What a wasted time with this terrible tool!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I update Git to version 1.9 and this issue is fixed.

During push/commit, the Git Bash will ask for Github's account & password.

Answer (score 0):

I used git-credential-winstore before.
When I reinstalled my Windows, that error popep up.
I resolve the issue by downloading git-credential-winstore again in my PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also using GitHub from Visual Studio. I went to Team Explorer->Manage Connections->Connect a Project then Select Github which re-authenticated me in the web browser. I was then able to push my changes.