# Can't push after Git Update

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

I've just updated from Git 1.7.11 to 1.8.5

Now when trying to push to bitbucket I'm getting the following message:

> fatal: could not read Password for 'https://xxxxxx@bitbucket.org': No
>   such file  or directory

Where xxxxx is my username.

Pushing on other machines which are still on 1.7 is working ok.

What would cause this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I've tried a system restart to no avail

Comment: Rolling back to 1.7.11 did not help

Comment: Tried a different network incase I was having network issues - no luck

Comment: This appears to not just effect this repository.  I've created a brand new clean repository on disk and on bitbucket and I get the same message 'No such file or directory'

Comment: What output you get from push command after setting `GIT_TRACE` environment variable to `true`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when push commits with Github: fatal: could not read Username](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871549/error-when-push-commits-with-github-fatal-could-not-read-username)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a bug in 1.8.5.2 msysgit (1.8.5.2-preview20131230). See [the report](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/153) and a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/msysgit/s4dB8Nv9V4c/55-cGPdPYmAJ) with a way to workaround

Comment: I've created an [unofficial fix release (1.8.5.4)](https://github.com/nevik/git/releases/tag/v1.8.5.4.msysgit.nevik.0) for people who want to or need to use a Git version newer than 1.8.4. This should serve as an intermediate solution until a new official release is made.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
git remote add origin https://username:password@bitbucket.org/repo.git
```

obviously for username put your username

password put your password

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily the best answer - but in the end I resolved this by removing/uninstalling git altogether and then reinstalling.

I have no idea why I needed to do this.  At present I've reinstalled 1.7.
I'll try an update again sometime and update this post.

Comment: Never ever use the installer. Always unzip the archive in a separate path and adjust `%PATH%` accordingly: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=portable&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount

Comment: @VonC And that recommendation is based on what argumentation?

Comment: @poke On Windows, you want to work only with *portable* software: no registry modification, no environment variable modified without your knowledge/consent, and the ability to fall back to the previous -- untouched -- git installation if the new one behave badly. Plus the installer has (or had) the nasty habit to set for you the `core.autocrl` global Git config to true. I have 4 years worth of answers explaining why this isn't a good idea (like http://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/6309).

Comment: *“you want to work only with portable software”* – No idea where you get this from, but I absolutely disagree. And the installer gives you configuration options to exactly specify if the environment should be modified etc.; it also lets you choose whether or not to enable `autocrlf`. Issues from the past are not relevant. The installer is definitely the recommended way to install “Git for Windows”.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a blind shot here, but are you able to re-add the remote without the username in the URL? I know in the old Git version, you needed to specify the username and password inline, but in the newer versions, it prompts you for the username and password if required.

```
git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/repo.git
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Using that command I get the response:
fatal:remote origin already exists

Comment: You will need to remove the current origin first, before trying to add it again - I should have mentioned: git remote rm origin

Comment: OK just tried removing and then adding without a username, but unfortunately no dice.  Still comes up with the 
'No such file or directory'

Comment: 'fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': No such file or directory'

Comment: Hmm, are you able to try cloning the repository to a new location using the link provided on BitBucket? Does that work?

Comment: Clone also comes back with 'fatal could not read password' 'No such file or directory' :/

Comment: OK, what OS are you using? How did you go about upgrading to Git 1.8.5? Did you also upgrade the dependencies (i.e. perl-Git)?

Comment: I'm on Windows and just visited http://git-scm.com/
downloaded the exe and ran through it

Comment: About as far as I can go for the moment. If there's no success in the next 12 hours, I'll give it a crack when I'm at work on my Windows machine and try to reproduce the problem for you.

Comment: No worries, thanks for trying.  I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling git and this seems to have fixed it for the time being.  I don't understand why at this point.

Comment: It could have changed the environment variables or modified something partially. A full re-install would have fixed this, but I would still be keen to find out what actually went wrong for future reference.