# Git can pull fine but not push "could not read username"

Tags: git, bash, github, ssh

I have been having this issue for a couple of days and I really don't know what to do.

I was pushing and pulling from a repository on github using git bash just fine for months; then, when their service went down temporarily, I reinstalled to make sure it wasn't me. Now, I can pull from the repository fine when the remote is set to the https. I can even clone it. However, when I try to push, I get

fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory.

I have tried deleting the origin remote and using the ssh, but then I get the "this repo doesn't exist" type errors (I have quadruple checked the ssh path, and generated my keys and all that"

I'm at a loss with what to do. Help?

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871549/error-when-push-commits-with-github-fatal-could-not-read-username might help you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a current bug in Git 1.8.5 that doesn't prompt for username/password on HTTPS: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/msysgit/s4dB8Nv9V4c/55-cGPdPYmAJ

Since your SSH isn't working, you can downgrade to 1.8.4 or use this temporary fix:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/project.git
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to why your answer is correct/should be accepted.