# Undo "git remote rm origin"

Tags: git, version-control, git-push

I encountered this error when doing a `git push`:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://usts.visualstudio.com': No such file or directory
```

Looks like I have hit a bug in git 1.8.5 as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20884273/45603

Google led me to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871910/45603

So, I ran `git remote rm origin` followed by `git remote add origin 'git@github.com:username/repo.git'`

Now I get the following message whenever I do a `git push`:

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

I would like to undo the `git remote rm origin` and rollback to git 1.8.4.

How do I undo `git remote rm origin`?

**Edit:** Running `git push --set-upstream origin master` (as advised by git) gives me the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host usts.visualstudio.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git SSH error: "Connect to host: Bad file number"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number)

Answer (score 1):

You can't "undo" a `git remote rm` call.

Besides, you don't need to undo the `git rm`. Just run the command as indicated.

Or just run `git push origin master` (or whatever branch you're on).

Answer (score 1):

`git remote rm origin` removes the connection to the remote server. `git remote add origin <user>@<url>` will recreate this connection. It looks as though when you ran `git remote add origin <user>@<url>` you entered the wrong url or the wrong username. Maybe just a typo.

To check, run `git remote -v`. This will display the connection string for the remote repository that is currently configured. Check it against the documentation provided by Visual Studio Online. If it is wrong, just do `git remote rm origin` again and then `git remote add origin <user>@<url>` again with the correct details.

If you are unsure what I mean or you have tried this and it doesn't work, then please post the exact commands you are using and the exact output of `git remote -v`, and I will see if I can find the error.

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't see this 2 days ago. You could post the command but with your username changed?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you need to tell git that your local master branch tracks the remote branch, which is what the error is telling you to do. By running `git push --set-upstream origin master`, you are telling git that the current branch tracks origin/master