# fatal: could not read Username for, No such device

Tags: git, jenkins

In my Jenkins job, I am configuring git in the following way:

```
sh("git config user.email my.email@google.com")
sh("git config user.name my-user-name")
sh("git tag ${BUILD_NUMBER}")
sh("git push origin --tags")
```

However, on the last line, when I try to push to my repository, I get the following error about the repository:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'http://my-git-repo.com:8000': No such device or address
```

What's wrong and how can I make it push to the repository?

Comment: Have you tryied using --global? Try this: git config --global user.name "my-user-name"

Comment: it's not your git `user.emai/user.name`, It's your `username/password` for authentication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub - fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147574/github-fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-no-such-file-o)

Answer (score 14):

You're looking for [`credential.username`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials). I don't know about the passphrase, but if you dislike `http://username:password@my-git-repo.com:8000` then put the credentials in your [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/) like so:

> The second most common type of Credentials is "Username and Password"
>   which can still be used in the `environment` directive, but results in
>   slightly different variables being set.
>
> ```
> environment {
>    SAUCE_ACCESS = credentials('sauce-lab-dev')
> }
> ```
>
> This will actually set 3 environment variables:
>
> ```
> SAUCE_ACCESS containing <username>:<password>
> SAUCE_ACCESS_USR containing the username
> SAUCE_ACCESS_PSW containing the password
> ```
>
> `credentials` is only available for Declarative Pipeline. For those
>   using Scripted Pipeline, see the documentation for the
>   `withCredentials` step.

Comment: This was a lifesaver. Using the environment credentials along with the command 'git remote set-url origin "https://$<ACCESS_VAR>@<GIT_REPO_URL>"' finally got git push working, after all the other solutions involving withCredentials failed.

Comment: Thank you. Although a workaround, It saved me after a couple of day.