# Cannot git clone in Jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, git-clone

I'm trying to clone only the last commit but get the following error in the jenkins job:

```
+ git config credential.username ****
+ git config user.name jenkins
+ git config user.email jenkins@comp.com
+ git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/base/my-repo.git

[Pipeline] sh
+ GIT_ASKPASS=true
+ git clone -b master --single-branch https://bitbucket.org/base/my-repo --depth=1 --bare ./last_commit
Cloning into bare repository './last_commit'...

fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': No such device or address
```

This is the function that I'm using as Jenkins shared library:

```
def call(url, branch, gitCredentialId) {
    try {
        withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: gitCredentialId, usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {
            sh("""                          
                git init
                git config credential.username ${env.GIT_USERNAME}
                git config user.name \"jenkins\"
                git config user.email \"jenkins@comp.com\"
                git remote add origin ${url}.git
            """)

            sh(returnStdout: false, script: """
                GIT_ASKPASS=true

                git clone -b ${branch} --single-branch ${url} --depth=1 --bare ./last_commit
                """)

            def email = sh(returnStdout: true, script: """
                cd ./last_commit
                git log -1 --format='%ae'
                """)

            return email.trim()
        }
    } finally {
        sh """
            git config --unset credential.username
            git config --unset credential.helper
        """
    }
}
```

What have I missed here? Has anyone faced the same issue? 
All I want to do to get the last comitter email.

Note that I have read this post here [fatal: could not read Username for, No such device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576857/fatal-could-not-read-username-for-no-such-device)

Although it's the same error as mentioned but the difference is that, in that post the OP faces the error for an already-checked-out code and they try to push whereas I don't have issue with checking out the code (using `git checkout`). My issue is that I can't clone the repository and there is no pre-existing source

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal: could not read Username for, No such device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576857/fatal-could-not-read-username-for-no-such-device)
Btw I was facing issues, once the password contained chars like `$`, `?` , etc...

Comment: I think private repo URL mentioned is not proper. i think it will some thing like "git clone https://${USER}@bitbucket.org/${USER}/{repo}.git"

Comment: or you can try with SSH inspite of https - > git clone git@bitbucket.org:${USER}/{repo}.git

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx I don't think that's the password, because we can do git checkout without any issue and with exactly the same code here

Comment: @RohitJindal I run the same command in my local machine with the same URL fomat and it works just fine but this happens only in Jenkins