# Not able to push changes to git repository using Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have created Jenkins pipeline for building code by cloning from git. I am able to clone repo , after building I want to push some files to git repo. I gave git credentials in Jenkins, still I am getting below error while pushing code.

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.xyz.com': No
> such device or address

I have seen many answers in google and tried that did not help me. Any ideas how we can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

See if you can follow [Handling credentials / Usernames and passwords](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#usernames-and-passwords) and use  environment variables.

> Jenkins' declarative Pipeline syntax has the credentials() helper method (used within the environment directive) which supports secret text, username and password, as well as secret file credentials

You can see a [concrete example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44911238/6309).