# How to resolve "fatal: unable to access " error

Tags: github, error-handling

I'm a beginner to GitHub.I need to send a pull request to the master branch.
when i typed the code

```
git push origin master
```

It gives me the error

> fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/www-prolificme-com/mahawiki/': The requested URL
>   returned error: 403

**Updated**

[image: screenshot of the Git Bash]

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636504/how-to-change-github-local-repo-git-config-credentials-to-circumvent-403/63647344#63647344

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71762364/8889086  try this

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned you are trying to pull from git but the command is git push. Anyways, most probably you are getting this error because your repo url is not set locally.

1. If this is the first time you are sending git request from your system, you might want to setup your username by `git config --global user.name "John Doe"`
2. If you have already used git on your system, try checking the git configuration on your system using `git config --list` command to check whether your repo URL is setup or not.
3. If the url is not setup run `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/www-prolificme-com/mahawiki/`
4. Run `git remote -v` to verify if your url is setup
5. `git add .`
6. `git commit -m "your message"`
7. `git push origin master`

Comment: I followed the steps you said,but i'm still getting the same error.why is that?

Comment: Can you please mention the steps you are following along with the output of `git config --list` command?

Comment: first i cloned the repository, then i executed 'git config --list ' then i saw website link,hence i executed git remote -v ,then git add. then 'git commit -v' and finally executed git push command. but i received the same error

Comment: Why are you using `git commit -v`? Try `git commit -m "your comment"` and `git push origin branch_name`, you can check branch name with `git branch`. Also, `git remote -v` does not executes anything, it only returns the current repository you are in.

Comment: still receiving the error,i have included the screenshot of the console.can you check the updated of my question..

Comment: Are you added as a contributor to the repository you are trying to push? The public repository only give read only access to anonymous users. You cannot push unless you are added as a contributor.

Answer (score 1):

Remove/Update the saved credentials:

1. Click Start
2. Search for 'Credential Manager'
3. Select 'Windows Credentials Manager' > 'Windows Credentials'
4. Search for the credentials that you want to remove/update
5. Click on the credential entry > Click 'Edit' or 'Remove'

Answer (score 0):

your repo is not setting locally 
so, you seemed crash message

first

```
git config --list
```

to showing your git repo set list
and

```
git remote set-url origin <your git repo address>
```

to access git repo and `git add .` to add your files to git container

```
git commit -m "your git commit message"
```

this is your git commit message version or anything possible

```
git push origin master
```

finally your files pushing on git repo 
it's done!
try it

Comment: Thank you for the help.i tried but didn't work.i'm getting the same error

Comment: intersting... first your git local repo to backup another folder and your git folder to delete
1. 'add a new folder'
2. that folder is git folder 'git init' to make git local repo
3. 'git clone https://github.com/www-prolificme-com/mahawiki/' to cloning your folder
4. backup folder to original git folder
5. git add .
6. git commit -m "message"
7. git push

Comment: i'm still receiving the error. i have uploaded the screenshot of the console above

Comment: i think may your permission denied error is github ssh key register error, make one of ssh and add on github account

Answer (score 0):

I got this same problem then I try to this below command.

step 1:

```
git config --global user.email "user email"
```

step 2:

```
git config --global user.name "user name"
```

After running those commands, you can use this command to push your code:

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set all credentials and other setups in the local machine, you might face this problem.

Currently, GitHub uses `'personal access token'` so when or after creating personal access token you must check the `Select scopes`.

[image]

You select all you need and then push again.
It will be pushed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing working please check if you have checked the below checkboxes while creating token

[image: Personal access tokens]