# how i fix it ?i tryed push my project to git hub but

Tags: java

This is my action :
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to namnguyenptitcn/Cinema-Management-System.git denied to kimvanha20051999.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/namnguyenptitcn/Cinema-Management-System.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: same question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988208/how-to-resolve-fatal-unable-to-access-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve "fatal: unable to access " error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988208/how-to-resolve-fatal-unable-to-access-error)