# Unable to push remote repository to my repo

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-push, git-pull

I cloned  and pulled a repository on a branch develop from github to my local repository and when i tried to 'git push origin develop' it to my repository, it brought the error below:

remote: Permission to adex001/Fast-Food-Fast.git denied to dlaw-code.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/adex001/Fast-Food-Fast.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

How do I rectify this?

Comment: Hi there, have a look at this question and see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988208/how-to-resolve-fatal-unable-to-access-error

Comment: you don't have permission to push into develop branch. you need to create a branch from develop and push new branch

Comment: How do I create a branch from develop?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not the owner or a collaborator to the repository you want to push from, you need to:

- [**fork** the repository first](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo)
  [image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/fork_button.jpg]
- change origin in your local cloned repository to your forked repository (that you own)

That is:

```
cd /path/to/local/clone
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin https://github.com/<me>/myForkedRepository
```