# how to push from colab to github

Tags: git, github, google-colaboratory

I cloned a public github repo of mine into my drive. I am able to use colab with the notebooks. I can also pull. I however face the following error when trying to push despite having correctly configurated:

```
!git config --global user.email "my_email"
!git config --global user.name "my_user"
```

When doing `!git push origin master` I get the following error:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

Has somebody encountered this problem before?

Comment: Have you tried "!git remote add origin https://<username>:<password>github@github.com/<username>/reponame.git" "!git push -u origin master" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147574/fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-no-such-file-or-directo)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+could+not+read+Username

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the options mentioned above worked for me. I finally found the answer in [this](https://medium.com/@chho_mailbox/great-post-thanks-for-sharing-541480eb6084) Medium article. Basically, the key line that I was missing was:

```
> !git remote add origin https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@github.com/<USERNAME>/reponame.git
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is how to clone, add a file, and push back

```py
uname = "korakot"
!git config --global user.email '$uname@gmail.com'
!git config --global user.name '$uname'

from getpass import getpass
password = getpass('Password:')
!git clone https://$uname:$password@github.com/korakot/myrepo
%cd myrepo
# create a file, then add it to stage
!git add hello.txt
!git commit -m 'commit message'  # commit in Colab
!git push origin master          # push to github
```

Comment: I tried this approach and it seems that you can no longer use password to access and edit a git repository.  The answer given by @Himanshu garg works.

Answer (score 7):

The answer marked as accepted is correct, but GitHub has **deprecated** the use of username password for HTTPS. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65350058/does-deprecation-of-basic-password-authentication-affect-github-deploy-keys) and [Github's blog](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/).

You should create a **personal access token** and use as follows:

```
!git remote add origin https://<USERNAME>:<Token>@github.com/<USERNAME>/reponame.git
```

To create your personal access token:

1. in your GitHub account go to settings
2. go to Developer settings
3. go to Personal access tokens
4. generate new token

Make sure to **save it** as you only see it once.

Comment: Thanks! Just in case some people encounter another error when using `add`, the solution works with `set-url`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028024/376454

Answer (score 4):

To copy a file from google drive. These steps are the only one that needs to be executed.

I use this method to push a large dataset (size ~ 200MB) to github using google drive to save the INTERNET DATA and TIME. Using this method any file or folder inside your google drive can be pushed using google's backend internet.

Steps :-

1. Push the below code section to colab Notebook.

   ```
   uname = "darkshadow013"
   !git config --global user.email 'email_address'
   !git config --global user.name 'darkshadow013'

   #Make a clone of github REPO
   !git clone https://<U_NAME>:<PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>@github.com/<U_NAME>/<REPO_NAME>

   #Copy file from either google drive after mounting using file browser
   !cp <PATH_OF_FILE_TO_COPY> /content/<REPO_NAME>
   ```
2. Mount Google drive.
3. This is an Optional Step, But must be performed if file size is >100MB as 100MB is the file_size limit of github.

   ```
   #Download git-lfs to Push Files larger than 100MB.
   !wget -O git-lfs.tar.gz https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases/download/v2.13.2/git-lfs-linux-amd64-v2.13.2.tar.gz
   !tar xzf git-lfs.tar.gz
   !bash ./install.sh
   !git lfs install
   %cd <REPO_NAME>
   #FILE_NAME is the file with size >100MB and you wants to PUSH to GITHUB
   !git lfs track <FILE_NAME>
   ```
4. Final Step is to add the file, commit and then push.

   ```
    !git add <FILE_NAME>
    !git commit -m 'commit message'  # commit in Colab
    !git push
   ```

That's it all you need to do is run this code and voila!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- `cd repo_directory`
- `git config --get remote.origin.url` to check the remote URL
- `git config -e --local` check/update the `[remote "origin"]` section
- `git config -e --global` check/update the `[user]` and `[http]` section

**Given the fact that you are using colab, in order to check your git configurations file , just use `! cat ~/.gitconfig` for --global , `! cat <repo_directory>/.git/config` for --local.

**In order to write your desired configuration files, use the `%%shell` cmd in a new cell, e.g for `<repo>/.git/config` same can be applied for `~/.gitconfig`:

```
%%shell
cat <<EOF >> <repo>/.git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
EOF
```

--**local**
By default, git config will write to a local level if no configuration option is passed. Local level configuration is applied to the context repository git config gets invoked in. Local configuration values are stored in a file that can be found in the repo's .git directory: .git/config

--**global**
Global level configuration is user-specific, meaning it is applied to an operating system user. Global configuration values are stored in a file that is located in a user's home directory. ~ /.gitconfig on unix systems and

Answer (score 0):

1. First step is to produce a 'Personal access tokens'
   go to https://github.com -> settings ->  Developer settings -> Personal access tokens -> Generate new token
   name it, Scopes it's access, copy the token string `ghp_some_string` in your text file
2. in Google colab

   2.1: `!git clone https://github.com/some_user/some_file.git`

   2.2: navigate to the folder `%cd ...`  -> make the desired modifications

   2.3:

```
!git config --global user.email "your@mail.com"
!git config --global user.name "your_github_username"
!git pull
!git add * :/
!git commit -m 'some_modif'
!git push https://ghp_some_string@github.com/some_user/some_file.git
```

Answer (score 0):

The below steps worked successfully for me:

**Generate a Personal Access Token on GitHub:**

- Navigate to your Git account settings, then Developer Settings.
- Click the Personal access tokens menu, then click Generate new token.
- Select repo as the scope. The token will be applicable for all the specified actions in your repositories.
- Click Generate Token.

The generated token will look like ghp_qf32Wli6qjO......

**Execute below commands in collab or your command prompt:**

```
!git config --global user.name "Provide user name"
!git config --global user.email "Provide email"
username = 'Provide git user name'
git_token = 'Provide git token'
repository = 'Provide git repository name'
!git remote add origin https://{git_token}@github.com/{username}/{repository}.git
```

Comment: This shows up in my case: error: key does not contain a section: anshumansinha16 <myusername>
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Answer (score 0):

If the token doesn't work go to File and click on Save a copy. In Github, allow Colab access to GitHub.