# fatal: cannot run /snap/code/79/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: github

I have been trying to push the code to Github but getting error as below.

> $ git push fatal: cannot run
> /snap/code/79/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh:
> No such file or directory

Iam able to push by providing username and Personal access Token but it valid for only in that push command. Next time when i try to push the code it is again asking for credentials followed by the error.

Comment: Probably a duplicate question. This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147574/fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-no-such-file-or-directo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147574/fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-no-such-file-or-directo)

Comment: Hi Venkata, But looking on the error we are getting it looks like an issue with other file. Also iam able to see the username and other details with command git config --list

Answer (score 21):

One solution that worked for me was to restart VS Code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am finding this simple approach weird, but it worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

Ya, simply restart your vs code and it will ask then for permission from GitHub
when you will push your code to remote

Answer (score 0):

vscode running as a snap could not get access to askpass to retrieve saved passwords in ubuntu

Answer (score -2):

The error you're encountering suggests that Git is unable to locate the `askpass.sh` script required for authentication. Restarting your VSCode clear the error.

However, if it fails you can configure Git to use a different authentication method that doesn't rely on the `askpass.sh` script. You can use SSH keys for authentication, which will allow you to push code without entering your credentials each time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).