# Github Actions: Could not read Username for 'https://github.com' when maven-release-plugin runs release:perform

Tags: github, github-actions, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to create a GitHub Actions workflow which releases my maven project (using maven-release-plugin) and pushes the (signed) artifacts to the central maven repository.

The `release:prepare` step runs fine (pushes tags to GitHub), but on the `release:perform` **I'm getting the following error:**

```
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:perform (default-cli) on project myproject: Unable to checkout from SCM
Error:  Provider message:
Error:  The git-clone command failed.
Error:  Command output:
Error:  Cloning into '/home/runner/work/myproject/myproject/target/checkout'...
Error:  fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

**Here's my workflow:**

```
name: Release MyProject

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      releaseVersion:
        description: 'Release version'
        required: true
        type: string
      developmentVersion:
        description: 'Development version after release'
        required: true
        type: string
      publishTo:
        description: 'Publish to'
        required: true
        default: 'MavenCentral'
        type: choice
        options:
          - 'MavenCentral'
          - 'none (dry run)'

env:
  RELEASE_VERSION: ${{ inputs.releaseVersion }}
  DEVELOPMENT_VERSION: ${{ inputs.developmentVersion }}
  PUBLISH_TO: ${{ inputs.publishTo }}

jobs:
  build_release:
    name: build myproject release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '11.0.11'
          distribution: 'zulu'
          cache: 'maven'
          server-id: 'ossrh' # Value of the distributionManagement/repository/id field of the pom.xml
          server-username: MAVEN_USERNAME # same name as below env variable
          server-password: MAVEN_PASSWORD # same name as below env variable
          gpg-private-key: ${{ secrets.PGP_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          gpg-passphrase: GPG_PASSPHRASE # same name as below env variable
      - name: Configure git user
        run: |
          git config user.email "girders@netcetera.com"
          git config user.name "Github Actions Bot"
      - name: Maven clean
        run: mvn --batch-mode clean release:clean
        shell: bash
      - name: Maven release:prepare
        run: mvn --batch-mode -DdryRun=${{ env.PUBLISH_TO == 'none (dry run)' }} -DdevelopmentVersion=$DEVELOPMENT_VERSION -DreleaseVersion=$RELEASE_VERSION release:prepare
        shell: bash
      - name: Maven release:perform
        run: mvn --batch-mode -DdryRun=${{ env.PUBLISH_TO == 'none (dry run)' }} release:perform
        shell: bash
        env:
          MAVEN_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.MAVEN_CENTRAL_USERNAME }}
          MAVEN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MAVEN_CENTRAL_PASSWORD }}
          GPG_PASSPHRASE: ${{ secrets.PGP_PASSPHRASE }}
```

**SCM section of the pom:**

```
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/mycompany/myproject.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/mycompany/myproject.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/mycompany/myproject</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>
```

**Here's the `settings.xml` generated by the `setup-java@v3` action:**

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <username>${env.MAVEN_USERNAME}</username>
      <password>${env.MAVEN_PASSWORD}</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>gpg.passphrase</id>
      <passphrase>${env.GPG_PASSPHRASE}</passphrase>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

**How do I get git to work in the `release:perform` step?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub - fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147574/github-fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-no-such-file-o)

Comment: I am having the same issue on a private github repo - release:plan runs fine, and it fails on release:perform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I changed the repository's visibility from `private` to `public` which resolved the issue for me.

The configuration worked as posted.

Comment: Making it public is not a good solution for all the cases. We should be able to use it with private repo also.

Comment: I dont have the option to make my repo public :(

Answer (score 0):

The git clone error may be related to:
[GitHub - fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147574/github-fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-no-such-file-o)

This would probably be related to some credential issue with the repo you are attempting to clone.

You could also try:

```
  - name: Maven release:perform
    run: |
      git config user.email "girders@netcetera.com"
      git config user.name "Github Actions Bot"
      mvn --batch-mode -DdryRun=${{ env.PUBLISH_TO == 'none (dry run)' }} release:perform
    shell: bash
    env:
      MAVEN_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.MAVEN_CENTRAL_USERNAME }}
      MAVEN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MAVEN_CENTRAL_PASSWORD }}
      GPG_PASSPHRASE: ${{ secrets.PGP_PASSPHRASE }}
```

You may explicitly add the git config user.email and user.name executions right before the mvn line.

You may also set:

```
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      persist-credentials: false
```

...only if the credentials from the checkout will be different than the target repo for the git clone from mvn

Also, I'm not sure if you can have spaces in your github user.name:

```
  git config user.name "Github Actions Bot"
```

may need to be revised to:

```
  git config user.name "Github-Actions-Bot"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately this did not help.

Comment: this seems to be a maven release plugin issue. The release:prepare is using the git credentials without problems

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the same error by instructing the scm plugin to use the 'github' server for the credentials.
This can be done by adding the following property in the `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <project.scm.id>github</project.scm.id>
</properties>
```

In my Maven `settings.xml` I have the following configuration for the github server:

```
<server>
  <id>github</id>                     
  <username>$GITHUB_ACTOR</username>
  <password>$GITHUB_TOKEN</password>
</server>
```