# Install from private repo in Cocoapods on Github Actions fails with: fatal: could not read Password for 'https://**@github.com': Device not configured

Tags: git, react-native, github, github-actions

I have seen various answers to similar problems but have not yet found one that solves my problem.

I have a 3rd party dependency that requires a password to authenticate against its private git repo. Locally, this works fine, as it prompts for the password, so I can enter it and then install correctly. This is then cached somewhere so I don't need to re-enter it.

However, running `pod install` in CI on github actions, I get an error:

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://**@github.com': Device not configured
```

How can I provide the password credential non-interactively in the CI so that I can install this dependency via my pod install?

A note - I am using React Native

Thank you for any assistance in advance!

I have tried a solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147574/github-fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-no-such-file-o) where I attempt to add the remote like so:

`git remote set-url origin https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/project.git`

I have also tried this with only the password. However it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to get the `https://user:password@github.com` syntax working locally, then you should be able to set the password as an encrypted secret in GitHub Actions. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets has some additional detail on where and how to do this, but the gist is that your secret is encrypted at rest; imported as an environment variable when the action runs; and available for the script to use as often as necessary (in case you have multiple external repos you need to import).