# python git push function works only on windows

Tags: python, git, github

Using the git module,this code works fine on windows

```py
def actionGitPush(self,message_label,dir):
        repo = git.Repo(dir )
        origin_url = repo.remotes.origin.url
        #print(repo)
        repo.remotes.origin.push(refspec='master:master')
        message_label.append('Git Push to ' +  origin_url )
        message_label.append('==========')
```

but it gives this error on ubuntu.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/vbk/MAsTOCK/_PROJECT/_utils/scripts/python/devmgmt/devmgmt.py", line 234, in actionGitPush
    repo.remotes.origin.push(refspec='master:master')
  File "/home/vbk/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/remote.py", line 1118, in push
    return self._get_push_info(proc, progress, kill_after_timeout=kill_after_timeout)
  File "/home/vbk/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/remote.py", line 927, in _get_push_info
    proc.wait(stderr=stderr_text)
  File "/home/vbk/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 604, in wait
    raise GitCommandError(remove_password_if_present(self.args), status, errstr)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git push --porcelain -- origin master:master
  stderr: 'fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address'
```

I can't figure  what's going on.

Comment: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com'

Comment: What library are you using, GitPython? Please add the tag for it.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you forgot to configure your username/password in the git environment on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this issue because You have not configured GitHub properly in
the new system.

You can refer to the doc for connecting to GitHub with SSH https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

You can refer to the similar issue face available on stackoverflow.[GitHub - fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147574/github-fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-no-such-file-o)