# Getting Fatal Error while cloning on github

Tags: github, clone, git-clone

I am trying to run the following command on GitBash on Windows 7:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/myfolder/myrepo
```

I ended up getting the following message:

```
Cloning into 'myrepo'...

fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directo
ry
```

Found some articles but none of them were related with `"cloning"`:

Some relevant articles I found are :https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/issues/176

2) [fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147574/fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-no-such-file-or-directo)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using msysgit 1.8.5.2, this could be the result of a bug.
(Initially [discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20871549/6309), and confirmed in [issue 153](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/153))

Try upgrading to msysgit 1.9.0.: [`PortableGit-1.9.0-preview20140217.7z`](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=portable&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount).

Comment: I am using GitBash and not mysysgit but yes, my version of git is 1.8.5.2. Is there a way I can upgrade it to 1.9.0 without uninstalling the current GitBash ?

Comment: @John it is a msysgit distro. You can unzip the 1.9 I mention in my answer anywhere you want, and add it to your PATH. It will include a git bash (and a git cmd).