# How to push to GitHub using Git Bash?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Whenever I need to push my new local commits to GitHub I use the Windows GitHub desktop application. I open it up and click the sync button. I want to be able to do it from the Git Bash command line. I think the command I want to use is:

`git push origin master`

but when I do that I get some sort of invalid username error. I tried this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871910/280319

but when I do that and `git push origin master`I get another error saying `git@github.com:user/repo.git` is an invalid repo.

Now I'm at the point where I changed my origin back to `https://github.com/user/repo.git`(I think that's what it was set to before). But since I did that my local repo is now not "pointing" to the correct remote(I can tell because `git status` doesn't list 1 out of sync commit and neither does the GitHub desktop app).

This is all just on a test repo of mine.

So what do I have to do so that I can push to GitHub using the Git Bash command line?

Comment: Did you get the `git@...` URL from the link on your `github` page?

Comment: Have you set a public ssh key into your account? What is the output of `ssh git@github.com`

Comment: tmarwen - I think that may have done something. I got: `Warning: ... added the RSA host key for IP address ... Hi username! You've successfully authenticated ...`. Now what?

Comment: Can you post the `origin` lines that show up when running `git remote -v`? That `git@github.com/user/repo.git` is a generic link name.

Comment: leigh - it's the github https one for both fetch and push. I changed it back to this as indicated in my post.

Comment: @Ryan is this question still relevant?

Comment: What does git remote show origin tell you?

Answer (score -1):

Usually what I do in this situation is just "start over". It is probably not the
optimal way to do this, but it works.

1. Back up your commits, for example to back up the last 4 commits that have not
   been pushed

   ```
   git format-patch -4
   ```
2. Re clone the repo

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/svnpenn/a
   ```
3. Apply your commits. Note since you said Windows, you might need to add
   `--keep-cr` here

   ```
   git am ../0001-type-magick-dev-null-exit.patch
   ```
4. try `push`ing again