# Save changes to GitHub using Git Bash

Tags: windows, git, bash, github

I'm new to both GitHub and Git. I created a repository on github.com and added some files to it. Then, I used git bash (on Windows) to download those files using `git clone github.com/username/repository.git`. So I've got the files on my computer. Now, I have edited some files and I want to send the new files to the master branch on my GitHub repository. I've actually read those questions:
[How to push to GitHub using Git Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315583/how-to-push-to-github-using-git-bash)
[Error when push commits with Github: fatal: could not read Username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871549/error-when-push-commits-with-github-fatal-could-not-read-username/20871910#20871910)

but I can't figure out any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. track the changes you wish to make

   git add --all
2. Commit your changes

   git commit -m "$message"
3. push your changes to github branch

   git push origin localbranchname:remotebranchName
4. create a pull request on github to master

It sounds like you might have removed your origin using those tutorials. On github, copy the address of the repo.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/... (the link)
```

before step 3

Comment: Exactly what I needed. No, I didn't remove my origin. Everything worked fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is

git remote rm origin
git remote add origin 'git@github.com:username/repo.git'