# git push with git-cola failing

Tags: git, github, git-cola

I started getting the following error a week ago when pushing with git-cola...I found something about a similar problem happening a lot a couple years ago but it didn't help at all.

```
"git push" returned exit status 128

Have you rebased/pulled lately?

Already up-to-date.

Pushing to https://github.com/slacktracer/lokapala.git
error: cannot run None: No such file or directory
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

When I push with the terminal it works just fine, so perhaps it is mostly a question about git-cola. Anyway, just wondering if anyone can help. I'm lost right now...

Comment: "I found something about a similar problem happening a lot a couple years ago but it didn't help at all." Are you referring to another question on Stack Overflow? **Which question?**

Comment: @Cupcake I wasn't referring to any specific stackoverflow question. But the question linked by VonC mentions it too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871549/error-when-push-commits-with-github-fatal-could-not-read-username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cannot run None: No such file or directory
```

That would mean your editor used for the commit message isn't properly set.
Check the value of `git config core.editor`

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

Check, as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21310193/6309), if you are not using a msysgit 1.8.5 (on Windows): more recent versions don't have this bug.

See if your config does have a `user.name` and `user.email` declared.

If https access fails consistently, try [switching to ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20884273/6309).

But for https, you also can create an [OAut token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use) and

```
git config remote.origin.url https://{token}@github.com/username/project.git
git config remote.origin.url https://{token}@github.com/slacktracer/lokapala.git
# or
git remote set-url origin https://{token}@github.com/slacktracer/lokapala.git
```

---

The [OP slacktracer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/553598/slacktracer) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966063/git-push-with-git-cola-failing/23966395?noredirect=1#comment36991618_23966395) that the issue seems limited on git-cola on lunbuntu.

- Using git-gui could be a workaround.
- Typing `git push` from the command-line allows to switch right back in any GUI.

The [issue 179](https://github.com/git-cola/git-cola/issues/179) can help, as well as launching `git cola` with:

```
GIT_COLA_TRACE=1 git cola
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I'm on lubuntu, so I can't have the msysgit problem, right? I can still push from the terminal and, just installed for testing, git-gui. It seems git-cola stopped asking for username and password... (pushing to github, I mean)

Comment: @slacktracer do you mean you can push to GitHub now? It is  possible git-cola has now cached your credentials.

Comment: No! I still can't push with git-cola. It doesn't work. Give me the aforementioned error. Ad it doesn't prompt me to user and password.
git-gui, I just installed it, does. It does work. I can push with it. As I can push from the terminal.

Comment: My usual workflow was using git-cola to push to github. If can't make it work as it did, I will start using git-gui. I'm sure it could be much worse... =)

Comment: @slacktracer or you could type git push, from the command-line, before switching back to git-cola or git-gui.

Comment: Sure! I'm just not used to do it. And fear it would get a bit more "complicated" with many branches and the sort. Perhaps I'm completely wrong though.
Anyway, I really liked git-cola. It was the perfect tool for me. Easy to use and made clear to me what was going on and what I was doing. =)
Thank you.

Comment: @slacktracer try a `GIT_COLA_TRACE=1 git cola` and see if it is more verbose. You can read more at https://github.com/git-cola/git-cola/issues/179.

Comment: Yes! I did try earlier to install from source but had a little problem. Reading your link I cleared my head and made my install work. And now I'm able to push from latest git-cola. Thank you for this last "push" in the right direction. ;) And sorry for the pun.

Comment: @slacktracer great! I have included said "last push" in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just purged config files, for me just reinstalling worked. '-'

```
 # apt-get purge git-cola
```

**EDIT: In fact, installing git-gui really solved it for me.**