# (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2, codeship

I've configured github repository in codeship already under **Repository** and add branch under **Deployment**. And

```
BRANCH_NAME="${CI_BRANCH}"
ROOT_FOLDER="/home/ubuntu/code"
EC2_SERVER="blah@blah.compute.amazonaws.com"
fetch_branch="cd $ROOT_FOLDER && git fetch origin" && echo $fetch_branch
ssh $EC2_SERVER $fetch_branch
pull_branch="cd $ROOT_FOLDER && git checkout $BRANCH_NAME && git pull
origin $BRANCH_NAME" && echo $pull_branch
ssh $EC2_SERVER $pull_branch
ssh $EC2_SERVER "rsync -rvI $ROOT_FOLDER/ /home/ubuntu/www/code/"
```

but I've found following error by Codeship while deploying.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The known_host part is an "info" message: it informs you that your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` now lists your remote aws instance.
This is not blocking.

But you need to add your ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub public ssh key to the `~blah/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the remote server if you want to open an ssh session on it.

See "[Amazon EC2 Key Pairs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)" or "[SSH Connections to AWS CodeCommit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-unixes.html)",  which both describe the same principle.

---

The "fatal: could not read Username for http..." means it needs to know which user is accessing the GitHub repo.

```
cd /path/to/aws/repo
git remote set-url origin https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/project.git
```

That is not very secure, as your password is part of the url.
Best would be to [use a credential manager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-gc1) to cache said password (as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40613782/6309)).
Or to use an [ssh url for that repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871910/6309).

Comment: Sorry, I've solved that error message and forgot to update error message of codeship. I've edited my question and please let me know how to solve it. Thanks.