# Fatal: could not read username for 'https //github.com' device not configured

Tags: git, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am trying to push code to github with SublimeGit plugin, but something weird occurs to me.

> Pushing to https://github.com/username/username.github.io.git
>
> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured

Have been taken a lot of search before asking, like [fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147574/fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-no-such-file-or-directo), [Fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886729/fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-no-such-device-or-addre).

But problem still remains, any effort will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub Action: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71975373/github-action-fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-device-n)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You get that error (`fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured`) when `git` needs to ask for a username or password and (a) the only mechanism available to it is to ask on the console and (b) there is no console available (git is not attached to a tty device, i.e., you're not running `git` interactively).

This commonly happens in an environment where you are invoking git from some sort of gui tool and no appropriate credentials helper has been configured.

There are a variety of ways of addressing this problem:

- One of the easiest is to move to using `ssh` authentication rather than `https`.
- You could hardcode the credentials for github into your local git repository, as described in the [gitcredentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) documentation.
- You could configure an appropriate helper application. One may already be configured, but `git` may simply not be able to find it.  The [gitcredentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) man page has information on this option as well.

Comment: "@bower_components/jquery.balloon.js": "https://github.com/urin/jquery.balloon.js.git#^1.0.3"

Comment: If anybody using SourceTree, similar error was fixed by going to Preferences -> tab Git -> section Git version -> button Use System Git, and select from the dialog 'git'. 
It appears that after an update it forgot where it's command line tools are

Comment: After converting to ssh don't forget to change your remote url https://gist.github.com/developius/c81f021eb5c5916013dc

Comment: @codrut answer helped me. Just remember to restart SourceTree then it works

Comment: @codrut That did it for me too. Thanks you. Could you perhaps put that in a dedicated answer? From your upvotes it looks like it helps many people.

Comment: @codrut - setting `credential.helper` to sourcetree did it for me. Source: https://gist.github.com/RockinPaul/6b012b106c4175469ee39bde12fb67f7

Comment: @codrut Bless you!! i'll post that as an answer maybe it is easier for others to see this

Comment: In our case, we were trying to pull from a repo that was accidently set as pravite. Normally if we run git pull we were asked to input username, but the interaction is impossible during a Jenkins pipeline process, so an error was thrown "No such device or address". Updating the repo to "public" fixed our issue.

Answer (score 87):

Mac OS:
Android Studio Preferences -> Git -> at bottom, Use Credentials helper (make sure it is checked)

Windows:
Android Studio File -> Settings -> Git -> Check Credentials Helper at bottom

Comment: Thanks, this one solved it for me, but I had to restart Android Studio as well before the push actually worked for me.

Comment: after this need restart android studio and made push again

Comment: And now Preferences has been renamed to Settings in macOS Ventura

Answer (score 17):

I just closed Android Studio and started it again. The problem is fixed.

Comment: Unbelievable, tnx)
got forget to restart guys..

Comment: Unbelievable... Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

@codrus's comment helped me fixing the issue on sourcetree
Go to Preferences -> tab Git -> section Git version -> button Use System Git, and select from the dialog 'git'.

Answer (score 3):

[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/RockinPaul/6b012b106c4175469ee39bde12fb67f7) helped a lot! Just 3 commands.

Comment: In my case, git was configured with sourcetree, fixing back to Mac OS keychain worked for me -> git config credential.helper osxkeychain

Answer (score 2):

What solved it for me was this:

1. I restarted android studio
2. I ran `flutter pub get`
3. Github then asked me for my username and password. I entered them. The password I entered was my github access token, not my actual github password.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Check this option in Android Studio File -> Settings -> Git -> Credentials Helper

If its not working even after checking 'Credentials helper' in settings then only restart the Android Studio and try to push code again.

Answer (score 1):

I restarted the Android Studio and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

On Mac Updating keychain access entry for github worked for me.

[refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68780572/1529129) for details on how to update keychain access entry.

Answer (score 0):

This should help solve this problem, since support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.Please download and instal Git Credential Manager: https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/releases/tag/v2.0.785
Then you can use Android Studio and push all changes. After push Git Credential Manager will ask you for validation, and all should works perfect after all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on google colab, running the clone command on the terminal instead of the notebook will, most probably, do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

For me, just install Github client for Mac fixed the issue.