# fatal: could not read Username When pushing to git using a cron job

Tags: bash, git, macos, cron

Hey I am trying to push code to git using a cron job on the Mac. I edit my crontab using `crontab -e` and have the following inside:

```
* 12 * * 1 ~/Dropbox/MD/sync.sh
* 12 * * 5 ~/Dropbox/MD/sync.sh
```

The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Dropbox/MD
/usr/bin/git add .
/usr/bin/git commit -m "Docs auto update"
/usr/bin/git push origin master
```

However the command fails and when I run `mail` I can check the error message which is: `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured`. How can I fix this issue? If I run the commands manually from the terminal I have no issues and I am not prompted for user credentials.

Any pointers on this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71895014/10705803

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When automating git tasks using SSH keys is recommended. You can setup SSH keys with push access by following these steps:

1. get the SSH key of the user(or generate one: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`)
2. copy contents of the public key (`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`)
3. Go to the project on github.com
4. Go to project settings
5. Choose `Deploy Keys` (https://github.com/user/project/settings/keys)
6. Choose add deploy key
7. Add your public key contents
8. Check `Allow write access`
9. Choose `Add Key`

Please note this will only work for repositories cloned with the following remote: `git@github.com:user/project.git`

The remote can be updated wit the following steps:

1. go to the repository folder on the server
2. run `git remote remove origin`
3. run `git remote add origin git@github.user/project.git`

Comment: This is great thanks! For the first step where you generate the SSH key of the user, is the email the GitHub account email?

Comment: That isn't required, the email isn't really relevant. I can be any email, it can help with keeping track of where the public key comes from when added to github. @Kex

Answer (score 1):

> If I run the commands manually from the terminal I have no issues and I am not prompted for user credentials.

That would be the case if your cron job does not run as you.

Git would check the value of `git config credential.helper` to see if the `github.com` username/password are cached (typically the [OSX Keychain for Mac](https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain)).
If the `cron` job is run as, for instance, root, it would not have that setting configured.

Note: check if a [plist in `$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents` would work better](https://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs), since [`launchd` might replace `cron`](https://superuser.com/a/1338468/141).