# Digitalocean and github (permission denied)

Tags: laravel, git, github, digital-ocean

I have a server on digitalocean and I want to connect it to git. (not even push anything, just connect).

When I test my connection with: `ssh -T git@github.com`.

I get an error of `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).` I have tried everything to try to make the connection work. On my computer the connection works, and the key on my root server is linked to my local `id_rsa`. The key is the same and I checked this with `ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on both my server and computer.

I am following this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

Any ideas? I am stuck and going insane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the public key created on your server on github.

- 1) On your server, copy the public key:

  ```
  cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  ```
- 2) Access: https://github.com/settings/keys
- 3) Click on "New ssh key" and paste you public key.

Comment: Deployment keys would be better for security reasons, you can limit the use to one repo and restrict the actions to read-only. Adding it to your account keys isn't recommended for deployments.  Checkout the following steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57638034/6310593

Comment: Ok I did this like 12 times, but today it worked after rebooting my system and adding a new key... I am happy now. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Recently I faced a similar issue on digital ocean.

1. start the ssh-agent `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`
2. add your private key `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Hope this helps and that it is the cause of your problem.

Comment: I have tried this a few times indeed. Nothing, still permission died. And the key that I am using is on my github under `keys`.

Comment: I am not able to do this in my specific user. `WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!` `Permissions 0775 for '/home/deployer/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.`

Comment: Well it kindly asks for stricter permissions on ssh keys. Something like ```sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub``` would do.