# Github Actions cloning could not read username

Tags: github-pages, github-actions

I have the following Github Actions workflow, which I'd like to generate Python documentation and upload to Github Pages:

```
name: documentation

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Standard drop-in approach that should work for most people.
      - uses: ammaraskar/sphinx-action@master
        with:
          docs-folder: "docs/"
      # Publish built docs to gh-pages branch.
      # ===============================
      - name: Commit documentation changes
        run: |
          git clone https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git --branch gh-pages --single-branch gh-pages
          cp -r docs/_build/html/* gh-pages/
          cd gh-pages
          touch .nojekyll
          git config --local user.email "<email>"
          git config --local user.name "<user>"
          git add .
          git commit -m "Update documentation" -a || true
          # The above command will fail if no changes were present, so we ignore
          # that.
      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          branch: gh-pages
          directory: gh-pages
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    # ===============================
```

However, it always errors out with:

```
Cloning into 'gh-pages'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

I'm new to Github Actions -- should I be running something before the clone command? I took this from the `sphinx-action-test` [repo](https://github.com/ammaraskar/sphinx-action-test).

Comment: I'd recommend actions like https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages and  https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action

Answer (score -2):

I'm located answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274484/fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-device-not-configured). Looks like actions cannot handle tty input and throw error