# GitHub Action: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I was trying to make `git clone` with Github Action on a private repo, but I am not sure how should I configure it to connect to GitHub with SSH. It is a macOS runner by the way.

At this moment, the `actions/checkout` is working fine but when I call `git clone` directly, this error is thrown.

The .yml file is provided below:

```yaml
name: Release IOS
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - github-action
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build IPA and upload to TestFlight
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}
      - name: Check Github User
        run: |
          git --version
          git config user.name 'MyUsername'
          git config user.email 'MyEmail'
          git config user.name
          git config user.email
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14.17.0
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      - name: Set up SSH
        uses: pioug/la-cle@v1.1.0
        with:
          GH_SSH_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      - name: Try copy a private repo
        run: git clone https://github.com/MyUsername/MyRepo.git
```

Comment: That error implies that something (Git, ssh, whatever it might be) is trying to read a secret from `/dev/tty`, i.e., the human who's sitting at a keyboard monitoring the run. Since there is no such human, `/dev/tty` produces the error you see. The trick now is to figure out (a) what's trying to read from `/dev/tty` and (b) why. (The `https://` part is a clue here: this is not using ssh.)

Comment: @torek Thanks! I just changed it to ssh and it works fine now. Perhaps you can post it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @torek noted, the error is trying to read credentials from your terminal since it exhausted other options (config etc.)

Since you're setting up ssh in the previous step then it seems like your intention is to use ssh so you should change the url to ssh.

```
run: git clone git@github.com:MyUsername/MyRepo.git
```

Note that there's other options as well.  You could still use https but use the git extraheader cli option along with a PAT.  That's actually [what we do in actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/2541b1294d2704b0964813337f33b291d3f8596b/src/git-auth-helper.ts#L56) for common situations.

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/How+do+I+clone+a+git+repository+with+extraHeader

From that site for completeness:

```
PAT="mypat123"
REPO_URL="https://myorg@dev.azure.com/myorg/myrepo/_git/myrepo/"
AUTH=$(echo -n "x-access-token:$PAT" | openssl base64 | tr -d '\n')
git -c http.$REPO_URL.extraheader="Authorization: Basic $AUTH" clone $REPO_URL --no-checkout --branch master
```

Basically you have it pass your PAT as a base64 encoded header.