# Using ssh-agent with docker on macOS

Tags: macos, docker, ssh, boot2docker

I would like to use ssh-agent to forward my keys into the docker image and pull from a private github repo.

I am using a slightly modified version of https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker with boot2docker on Yosemite.

```
ssh-add -l
...key details
boot2docker up
```

Then I use the command which I have seen in a number of places (i.e. https://gist.github.com/d11wtq/8699521):

```
docker run --rm -t -i -v $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent my_image /bin/bash
```

However it doesn't seem to work:

```
root@299212f6fee3:/# ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

root@299212f6fee3:/# eval `ssh-agent -s`
Agent pid 19

root@299212f6fee3:/# ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.

root@299212f6fee3:/# ssh git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.128' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the file $SSH_AUTH_SOCK?

Answer (score 27):

Since version `2.2.0.0`, docker for macOS allows users to access the host’s SSH agent inside containers.

Here's an example command that let's you do it:

```bash
docker run --rm -it \
-v /run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock:/ssh-agent \
-e SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/ssh-agent" \
my_image
```

Note that you have to mount the specific path (`/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock`) instead of the path contained in `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable, like you would do on linux hosts.

Comment: After more digging : Works only if the user inside the container is root I think (otherwise he cannot access the socket in the VM)

Comment: On my mac OS Big Sur there's no such path `/run/host-services`. Why? Should I install something?

Comment: @Salivan I also don't have this path myself. This is a "magic" mount - docker knows how to handle this path when it sees it. Did you try it out?

Comment: @JakubKukul yep, and it worked. Why isn't it documented anywhere? Or at least my google isn't able to find the documentation where this is mentioned.

Comment: @Salivan Ideally this should be documented somewhere, yes. I found out about it by following this Github issue's thread: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/410

Comment: Here's the doc as of today https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#ssh-agent-forwarding

Answer (score 7):

A one-liner:

Here’s how to set it up on Ubuntu 16 running a Debian Jessie image:

```
docker run --rm -it --name container_name \
-v $(dirname $SSH_AUTH_SOCK):$(dirname $SSH_AUTH_SOCK) \
-e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK my_image
```

https://techtip.tech.blog/2016/12/04/using-ssh-agent-forwarding-with-a-docker-container/

Comment: This looks very promising, but on OS X I'm getting a `Permission denied (publickey).` error. Perhaps it's because on non-linux hosts Docker is running in it's own WM?

Answer (score 4):

I expanded on @wilwilson's answer, and created a script that will setup agent forwarding in an OSX boot2docker environment.

https://gist.github.com/rcoup/53e8dee9f5ea27a51855

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use a unique ssh socket name per-invocation of this script
SSH_SOCK=boot2docker.$$.ssh.socket

# ssh into boot2docker with agent forwarding
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_boot2docker \
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -o IdentitiesOnly=yes \
    -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
    -o LogLevel=quiet \
    -p 2022 docker@localhost \
    -A -M -S $SSH_SOCK -f -n \
    tail -f /dev/null

# get the agent socket path from the boot2docker vm
B2D_AGENT_SOCK=$(ssh -S $SSH_SOCK docker@localhost echo \$SSH_AUTH_SOCK)

# mount the socket (from the boot2docker vm) onto the docker container
# and set the ssh agent environment variable so ssh tools pick it up
docker run \
    -v $B2D_AGENT_SOCK:/ssh-agent \
    -e "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent" \
    "$@"

# we're done; kill off the boot2docker ssh agent
ssh -S $SSH_SOCK -O exit docker@localhost
```

Stick it in `~/bin/docker-run-ssh`, `chmod +x` it, and use `docker-run-ssh` instead of `docker run`.

Comment: I created a version that works with docker-machine, now that Docker is recommending against using boot2docker. https://gist.github.com/leedm777/923706741c8296869e7d

Comment: dave - have you tried using this with docker-compose? Not sure how to modify your example to work with statically defined environment variables in docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score 1):

For me accessing ssh-agent to forward keys worked on OSX Mavericks and docker 1.5 as follows:

1. ssh into the boot2docker VM with `boot2docker ssh -A`. Don't forget to use option -A which enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.
2. Inside the boot2docker ssh session:

   ```
   docker@boot2docker:~$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
   /tmp/ssh-BRLb99Y69U/agent.7750
   ```

This session must be left open. Take note of the value of the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environmental variable.

3. In another OS X terminal issue the docker run command with the SSH_AUTH_SOCK value from step 2 as follows:

   ```
   docker run --rm -t -i \
     -v /tmp/ssh-BRLb99Y69U/agent.7750:/ssh-agent \
     -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent my_image /bin/bash
   root@600d0e9b443d:/# ssh-add -l
   2048 6c:8e:82:08:74:33:78:61:f9:9a:74:1b:65:46:be:eb         
   /Users/dev/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
   ```

I don't really like the fact that I have to keep a boot2docker ssh session open to make this work, but until a better solution is found, this at least worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue, and was able to make things pretty seamless by using ssh in master mode with a control socket and wrapping it all in a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh   

ssh -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -p 2222 -A -M -S ssh.socket -f docker@127.0.0.1 tail -f /dev/null

HOST_SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(ssh -S ssh.socket docker@127.0.0.1 env | grep "SSH_AUTH_SOCK" | cut -f 2 -d =)

docker run -v $HOST_SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent \
       -e "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent" \
       -t hello-world "$@"

ssh -S ssh.socket -O exit docker@127.0.0.1
```

Not the prettiest thing in the universe, but much better than manually keeping an SSH session open IMO.

Comment: Meanwhile newes docker complains:
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume spec ":/ssh-agent": invalid volume specification: ':/ssh-agent'.

Answer (score 1):

Socket forwarding doesn't work on OS X yet.  Here is a variation of @henrjk answer brought into 2019 using *Docker for Mac* instead of *boot2docker* which is now obsolete.

1. First run a ssh server in the container, with /tmp being on the exportable volume.  Like this

   ```
    docker run -v tmp:/tmp -v \
    ${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys:ro \
    -d -p 2222:22 arvindr226/alpine-ssh
   ```
2. Then ssh into this container with agent forwarding

   ```
    ssh -A -p 2222 root@localhost
   ```
3. Inside of that ssh session find out the current socket for ssh-agent

   ```
    3f53fa1f5452:~# echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
    /tmp/ssh-9zjJcSa3DM/agent.7
   ```
4. Now you can run your real container.  Just make sure to replace the value of SSH_AUTH_SOCK below, with the value you got in the step above

   ```
    docker run -it -v tmp:/tmp  \
    -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-9zjJcSa3DM/agent.7 \
    vladistan/ansible
   ```

Comment: Still useful and working on Docker Desktop for Mac in Aug,2022 for deploying rails 7 app using capistrano agent forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

By default, boot2docker shares only files under `/Users`. `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is probably under `/tmp` so the `-v` mounts the agent of the VM, not the one from your mac.

If you setup your VirtualBox to share `/tmp`, it should be working.

Comment: This sounds promising, could you provide some more information on how to do this? I found this: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#virtualbox-guest-additions but I'm relatively new to docker

Comment: Open your virtualbox, right click on the boo2docker vm, settings, shared directires, click the add button, enter /tmp, tick automount and permanent. However, after testing, it appears that shared directory does not allow you to share the socket, so it will not work.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. SSH_AUTH_SOCK is a Unix socket, not a file, so it can't be shared with VirtualBox the way files are.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

This error [occurs when](http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/12/understanding-ssh-agent-and-ssh-add/) `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` env var is set incorrectly on the host or not set at all. There are various workarounds you could try. My suggestion, however, is to [dual-boot Linux and macOS](https://habd.as/post/dual-boot-manjaro-mojave-macbook-pro/).

Additional resources:

- [Using SSH keys inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136389/using-ssh-keys-inside-docker-container?noredirect=1&lq=1) - Related Question
- [SSH and docker-compose](https://medium.com/@vanuan/ssh-and-docker-compose-7bce10b67765) - Blog post
- [Build secrets and SSH forwarding in Docker 18.09](https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/build-secrets-and-ssh-forwarding-in-docker-18-09-ae8161d066) - Blog post