# SSH Agent forwarding inside docker compose container

Tags: docker, ssh-keys, docker-compose

`Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`

I am following the [approach of mounting the `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` as a volume](https://gist.github.com/d11wtq/8699521), but doing so with compose.

### Setup

`~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM atlashealth/ruby:2.2.2

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -qy build-essential libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev \
            g++ qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev xvfb dbus \
            libmysqlclient-dev \
            mysql-client openssh-client git && \

    # cleanup
    apt-get clean && \
    cd /var/lib/apt/lists && rm -fr *Release* *Sources* *Packages* && \
    truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log
```

Compose yaml:

```
web:
  build: "."
  environment:
  - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
  volumes:
  - "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent"
```

**NOTE:** I have interpolation running on my compose, so `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is substituted with `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ZxGtZy6a9w/Listeners` for example.

I have forwarding setup on my host OSX properly, it works against another ubuntu host.

### Run

`docker-compose run web bash`

### In-Container

When I run `ssh-add -L`, it states `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`

When I run `ssh-agent`, it yields

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-vqjuo7FIfVOL/agent.21; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=22; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 22;
```

When I run `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` from bash, it yields `/ssh-agent`

### Question

It seems that compose is making the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` available to `bash`, but it seems that the `ssh-agent` is not getting that same `env`.  What am I missing?

Comment: Would https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/551 or https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1633 help?

Comment: #1633 is unnecessary, I mentioned in my `NOTE` that I have interpolation running.  Thanks for pointing me to #551, [this comment is similar](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/551#issuecomment-115284241).

Comment: For docker desktop for mac, this works https://stackoverflow.com/a/56404737/60072

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved it using [whilp/ssh-agent](https://github.com/whilp/ssh-agent), though you should note that this is **not** using `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` directly and requires an additional long running container.  I'll integrate this approach into [docker-rails](https://github.com/alienfast/docker-rails/issues/19) for ease of use.

1. Start a long running container
   `docker run -d --name=ssh-agent whilp/ssh-agent:latest`
2. Add your key
   `docker run --rm --volumes-from=ssh-agent -v ~/.ssh:/ssh -it whilp/ssh-agent:latest ssh-add /ssh/id_rsa`
3. List your keys
   `docker run --rm --volumes-from=ssh-agent -v ~/.ssh:/ssh -it whilp/ssh-agent:latest ssh-add -L`
4. bash into a container and check the key with `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`

My yaml looks like:

```
web:
    build: .
    working_dir: /project
    ports:
      - "3000"

    environment:
      # make ssh keys available via ssh forwarding (see volume entry)
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent/socket

    volumes_from:
      # Use configured whilp/ssh-agent long running container for keys
      - ssh-agent
```

Comment: There have been some changes to the `whilp/ssh-agent` so I use a different approach now and can't tell you with certainty that this works any more.  If you are looking for something simple and the container runs on a host with keys configured, you can use `volumes:

  - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh`

Comment: This approach still works for me but the environment variable should be `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh/auth/sock`, and you will also need to configure a top-level external volume--"ssh-agent" in this case--and set it as external (volumes_from is deprecated). On your docker-compose, set each service to mount the ssh-agent directory and add your keys individually

Answer (score 1):

The previous accepted answer using [whilp/ssh-agent](https://github.com/whilp/ssh-agent) did not work for me for some reason (it worked before but since last changes it doesn't and I don't know why) so I created my own agent container:

[docker-ssh-agent](https://github.com/andreasur/docker-ssh-agent)

based on minimal `alpine:3.4` base image. So anyone still having trouble with this on OSX, check the `README` it's now really easy to get it up and running!