# Inject host's SSH keys into Docker Machine with Docker Compose

Tags: ssh, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am using Docker on Mac OS X with Docker Machine (with the default boot2docker machine), and I use docker-compose to setup my development environment.

Let's say that one of the containers is called "`stack`". Now what I want to do is call:

```
docker-composer run stack ssh user@stackoverflow.com
```

My public key (which has been added to `stackoverflow.com` and which will be used to authenticate me) is located on the host machine. I want this key to be available to the Docker Machine container so that I will be able to authenticate myself against `stackoverflow` using that key from within the container. Preferably without physically copying my key to Docker Machine.

Is there any way to do this? Also, if my key is password protected, is there any way to unlock it once so after every injection I will not have to manually enter the password?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can add this to your docker-compose.yml (assuming your user inside container is root):

```
volumes:
    - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
```

Also you can check for [more advanced solution with ssh agent](https://gist.github.com/d11wtq/8699521) (I did not tried it myself)

Comment: Note this solution may fail if your SSH keys belong to a user on the host machine

Comment: Whilst you can do this at run time, you won't be able to access the volume at build time.

Comment: Not working on Windows either. `Permissions 0755 for '/root/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.`

Comment: You can add `:ro` at the end of this snippet to mount the keys read-only, this typically bypasses the warning from SSH about permissions, but if your key has a passphrase (it really SHOULD) you still need to do some trickery with ssh-agent.

Comment: Another important note is that with this as a volume

Answer (score 55):

**WARNING**: This feature seems to have limited support in Docker Compose and is more designed for Docker Swarm.

(I haven't checked to make sure, but) My current impression is that:

- In Docker Compose secrets are just bind mount volumes, so there's no additional security compared to volumes
- Ability to change secrets permissions with Linux host may be limited

See answer comments for more details.

---

Docker has a feature called secrets, which can be helpful here. To use it one could add the following code to `docker-compose.yml`:

```
---
version: '3.1' # Note the minimum file version for this feature to work
services:
  stack:
    ...
    secrets:
      - host_ssh_key

secrets:
  host_ssh_key:
    file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then the new secret file can be accessed in `Dockerfile` like this:

```
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh && ln -s /run/secrets/host_ssh_key ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Secret files won't be copied into container:

> When you grant a newly-created or running service access to a secret, the decrypted secret is mounted into the container in an in-memory filesystem

For more details please refer to:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#secrets

Comment: Hi astyagun : I agree that using the Secrets feature is a good way to approach this, but to make your answer better it would be useful to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference.

Comment: Thanks. added examples

Comment: Unfortunately linking id_rsa will not work, SSH will return with error, as link has different permissions. So, you still will need to copy the file, and keep RO permissions. But the good point is, that you can use `ssh -i /run/secrets/host_ssh_key ...` parameter, as the secret file has RO permission

Comment: @Kostanos Will adding `chown -h $(id -u):$(id -g) ~/.ssh/id_rsa` after creating a link help?

Comment: no, already tried. For now I'm copying the file instead of making link. anyway the image is in my PC, and I don't plan to publish it. So, I'm ok with security here

Comment: Really puzzled by this answer. According to the docs secrets didn't come about until v3.5. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-33

Also trying this locally secrets don't seem to be available during build.
ls: cannot access '/run/secrets': No such file or directory

Comment: According to the "Long Syntax" version of the documentation, you can set the permissions of the secrets file in the `docker-compose.yml` using the key `mode`. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#secrets

Comment: Note that secrets are a "swarm mode feature" as pointed in https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4994 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955542/how-to-read-external-secrets-when-using-docker-compose . It will not mount the secrets in docker-compose up.

Comment: SWARM ONLY! Arrrrgh

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect mentioned limitations

Comment: @AntonStyagun updated link for secrets docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#secrets

Answer (score 40):

If you're using OS X and encrypted keys this is going to be PITA. [Here are the steps](https://medium.com/@vanuan/ssh-and-docker-compose-7bce10b67765) I went through figuring this out.

### Straightforward approach

One might think that there’s no problem. Just mount your ssh folder:

```
...
volumes:
  - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh:ro
...
```

This should be working, right?

### User problem

Next thing we’ll notice is that we’re using the wrong user id. Fine, we’ll write a script to copy and change the owner of ssh keys. We’ll also set ssh user in config so that ssh server knows who’s connecting.

```
...
volumes:
  - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh-keys:ro
command: sh -c ‘./.ssh-keys.sh && ...’
environment:
  SSH_USER: $USER
...

# ssh-keys.sh
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
cp -r /root/.ssh-keys/* ~/.ssh/
chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) ~/.ssh

cat <<EOF >> ~/.ssh/config
  User $SSH_USER
EOF
```

### SSH key passphrase problem

In our company we protect SSH keys using a passphrase. That wouldn’t work in docker since it’s impractical to enter a passphrase each time we start a container.
We could remove a passphrase (see example below), but there’s a security concern.

```
openssl rsa -in id_rsa -out id_rsa2
# enter passphrase
# replace passphrase-encrypted key with plaintext key:
mv id_rsa2 id_rsa
```

### SSH agent solution

You may have noticed that locally you don’t need to enter a passphrase each time you need ssh access. Why is that?
That’s what SSH agent is for. SSH agent is basically a server which listens to a special file, unix socket, called “ssh auth sock”. You can see its location on your system:

```
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
# /run/user/1000/keyring-AvTfL3/ssh
```

SSH client communicates with SSH agent through this file so that you’d enter passphrase only once. Once it’s unencrypted, SSH agent will store it in memory and send to SSH client on request.
Can we use that in Docker? Sure, just mount that special file and specify a corresponding environment variable:

```
environment:
  SSH_AUTH_SOCK: $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
  ...
volumes:
  - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

We don’t even need to copy keys in this case.
To confirm that keys are available we can use ssh-add utility:

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
  echo "No ssh agent detected"
else
  echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
  ssh-add -l
fi
```

### The problem of unix socket mount support in Docker for Mac

Unfortunately for OS X users, Docker for Mac has a number of shortcomings, one of which is its inability to share Unix sockets between Mac and Linux. There’s an [open issue in D4M Github](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/483). As of February 2019 it’s still open.

So, is that a dead end? No, there is a hacky workaround.

### SSH agent forwarding solution

Luckily, this issue isn’t new. Long before Docker there was a way to use local ssh keys within a remote ssh session. This is called ssh agent forwarding. The idea is simple: you connect to a remote server through ssh and you can use all the same remote servers there, thus sharing your keys.

With Docker for Mac we can use a smart trick: share ssh agent to the docker virtual machine using TCP ssh connection, and mount that file from virtual machine to another container where we need that SSH connection. Here’s a picture to demonstrate the solution:

[image: SSH forwarding]

First, we create an ssh session to the ssh server inside a container inside a linux VM through a TCP port. We use a real ssh auth sock here.

Next, ssh server forwards our ssh keys to ssh agent on that container. SSH agent has a Unix socket which uses a location mounted to Linux VM. I.e. Unix socket works in Linux. Non-working Unix socket file in Mac has no effect.

After that we create our useful container with an SSH client. We share the Unix socket file which our local SSH session uses.

There’s a bunch of scripts that simplifies that process:
https://github.com/avsm/docker-ssh-agent-forward

### Conclusion

Getting SSH to work in Docker could’ve been easier. But it can be done. And it’ll likely to be improved in the future. At least Docker developers are aware of this issue. And even [solved it for Dockerfiles with build time secrets](https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/build-secrets-and-ssh-forwarding-in-docker-18-09-ae8161d066). And [there's a suggestion](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33048) how to support Unix domain sockets.

Answer (score 7):

You can forward SSH agent:

```
something:
    container_name: something
    volumes:
        - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent # Forward local machine SSH key to docker
    environment:
        SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /ssh-agent
```

Comment: You already gave that answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36648428/228370 And one note: This doesn't work for mac as @joe-saw pointed out, because unix domain sockets aren't proxied

Comment: How to get the local machine ssh agent directroy  /ssh-agent?

Comment: @famas23 this is the answer to your question: https://medium.com/trabe/use-your-local-ssh-keys-inside-a-docker-container-ea1d117515dc#3b26

Answer (score 5):

You can use multi stage build to build containers This is the approach you can take :-

```
Stage 1 building an image with ssh

FROM ubuntu as sshImage
LABEL stage=sshImage
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
WORKDIR /root/temp

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git npm 

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/ &&\
    echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa &&\
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa &&\
    touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts &&\
    ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN cp -R node_modules prod_node_modules
```

Stage 2: build your container

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/app

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./ ./

COPY --from=sshImage /root/temp/prod_node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 3006

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

add env attribute in your compose file:

```
environment:
      - SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}
```

then pass args from build script like this:

```
docker-compose build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"
```

And remove the intermediate container it for security. This Will help you cheers.

Comment: Last part can be added to docker_compose.yml `build.args`

Comment: Be aware though the keys are now stored in the image and even if you are using multistage, the key is still there in one of the layers.  potential security risk.

Comment: should add one more step to delete the key after cloning the repository from github

Answer (score 4):

Docker for Mac now [supports mounting the ssh agent socket](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#ssh-agent-forwarding) on macOS.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation on Docker's side has changed and no mention of `osxfs` can be found. Typical for Docker, poorly maintained or redirected documentation. Here at least is the archive.org version of your link: https://web.archive.org/web/20200414203352/https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#ssh-agent-forwarding

For posterity, key point: Requires `type: bind` in the volume mount.