# Gitea in Docker : SSH passthrough automation

Tags: git, docker, ssh, docker-compose, gitea

The [installation instructions](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/install-with-docker/#ssh-container-passthrough) of the Gitea documentation using docker describe the SSH passthrough procedure to make the `git clone git@mydomain.com:user/repo` command not failing.

I am new to docker but I am wondering, these few last 'manual' steps, can't they be automatised in a `docker-compose.yml` (and if so how would this file look like). It's not like a lot of steps but my understanding was that a docker container is supposed to be self-sufficient and with those steps it seems like it's not really.

Answer (score 0):

The SSH key creation should be done on the host, which is not what a `docker-compose.yml` is made for.
Everything happening on `/home/git/.ssh` could be scripted, separately from docker-compose.

The injection of the private key is done through a volume, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34933181/6309)