# bitbucket docker Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, docker, bitbucket

I´m making a docker file with the following code:

```
# Update aptitude with new repo
RUN apt-get update

# Install software 
RUN apt-get install -y git
# Make ssh dir
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/

# Copy over private key, and set permissions
ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa

# Create known_hosts
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
# Add bitbuckets key
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN chgrp 545 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# Clone the conf files into the docker container

RUN git clone git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxx/teste.git

RUN cd teste echo "# My project's README" >> README.md 
RUN git add README.md 
RUN git commit -m "Initial commit" 
RUN git push -u origin master
```

But when I build the file I got the following error:

> Cloning into 'teste'... Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key
>   for IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.x' to the list of known hosts. Permission
>   denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists. The command '/bin/sh -c git clone
>   git@bitbucket.org:xxxxxxxx/teste.git' returned a non-zero code:
>   128

I generated id_rsa with PuTTY key gen and is already stored in bitbucket.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you paste the whole Dockerfile please?

Comment: It´s the complete file, it just have a FROM ubuntu:16.04 in the top of it.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to add the corresponding private key in the container also. Since you mentioned that you generated the id_rsa key using putty, so that key is in your host machine.

What you need is to add the id_rsa key in your container and id_rsa.pub on bitbucket.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136389/using-ssh-keys-inside-docker-container) post might help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the public SSH key of the repository that's executing the command to the Access Keys section of the repository that you are trying to clone. I had the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53124545/1792699).