# How do you set an ssh key for docker image containing a private git repo?

Tags: github, docker, ssh-keys

I'm trying to get a docker image to build that requires it to clone a private github repo.

Comment: Here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24937401/2689986

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SSH keys inside docker container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136389/using-ssh-keys-inside-docker-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a hard time figuring out how to do this without copying my ssh keys over - my eventual solution was to use a github basic auth token in URL format passed into docker as a build argument.

## In Dockerfile

ARG GITHUB_URL
RUN git config --global url.$GITHUB_URL.insteadOf "https://github.com/"

RUN go get -u github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPO

## When Building

docker build -t YOUR_TAG . --build-arg GITHUB_URL="https://[YOUR_GITHUB_TOKEN]:x-oauth-basic@github.com/"