# Use github private repo deploy key inside build stage in docker for npm install

Tags: docker

My use case is that I have multiple express micro-services that use the same middleware and I would like to create a different repo in the format of an npm module for each middleware.

Every repo is a private repo and can have a deploy key attached (can be different keys or the same)

All of this works OK locally.  However when I try to use this with my docker-compose setup it fails on the npm install step, in the build stage.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN npm install --production
CMD npm start
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
   node-api:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

I understand this doesn't work because I don't have the deploy key I use on my local system in the Docker context.

I've looked around for a solution and none seem very easy/non hacky

1. Copy the key in and squash (CONS: not sure how I do this in a docker-compose file)http://blog.cloud66.com/pulling-git-into-a-docker-image-without-leaving-ssh-keys-behind/
2. Copy the key in on the build step and add to image. (CONS: Not very secure :( )
3. Use the key as a build argument. (CONS: see 2)
4. Dockerise something like https://www.vaultproject.io/ run that up first, add the key and use that within the node containers to get the latest key. (CONS: probably lots of work, maybe other issues?)
5. Use Docker secrets and docker stack deploy and store the key in docker secrets (CON: docker stack deploy has no support for docker volumes yet.  See here https://docs.docker.com/compose/bundles/#producing-a-bundle  unsupported key 'volumes')

My question is what is the most **secure** possible solution that is automated (minimal manual steps for users of the file)?  Time of implementation is less of a concern.  I'm trying to avoid checking in any sensitive data while making it easy for other people to run this locally.

Comment: For 5th point, what do you mean with `no support for volumes yet`? because here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#use-secrets-in-compose looks like they create volumes

Comment: should have been more specific, I mean in my compose file I use docker volumes https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/ for the containers to persist things like database files etc.  I can put secrets in compose but volumes are not supported yet.

Comment: I don't know if you mean this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-for-services-swarms-and-stack-files ? or something else?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/bundles/#producing-a-bundle I'm creating a bundle for the docker stack deploy (so I can use the secrets) when I create it I get the message unsupported key 'volumes', I believe you can set up volumes in a stack, just not through a compose file

Comment: so you want a stack from a bundle, because a docker stack supports the volume and other things (as in https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/beginner/chapters/votingapp.md)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, missed that off.  I have multiple extending compose files.  But that helps maybe I can combine it as a workaround

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's experiment with this new feature: [Docker multi stage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/)

> You can selectively copy artifacts from one stage to another, leaving behind everything you don’t want in the final image.

The idea is to build a temporary base image, then start the build again only taking what you want from the previous image. It uses multiple FROM in the **same** Dockerfile:

```
FROM node as base-node-modules
COPY your_secret_key /some/path
COPY package.json /somewhere
RUN npm install <Wich use your key>

FROM node #yes again!
...
...
COPY --from=base-node-modules /somewhere/node_modules /some/place/node_modules
...
... # the rest of your Dockerfile
...
```

Docker will discard everything what you don't save from the first FROM.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Check that your docker version supports this feature, because is too new (it is only required for the docker that builds, not the one that finally runs)

Comment: I only really want it for our CI builds and for local which will be OK with that version of docker.  Thanks again, I've been looking for a solution for ages!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)