# How to use ssh key inside docker container

Tags: macos, ssh, dockerfile

I am building dockerfile to create an image where I want to build a package. I want to pull this package inside the docker image. I need to do a git clone for that. I saw the discussion on this post :

[Using SSH keys inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136389/using-ssh-keys-inside-docker-container)

Based on that, here is the content in my Dockerfile :

`ENV SSH_HOME /Users/myid
ADD $SSH_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN  echo "    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config`

When I run docker build, I am getting an error due to relative path. If I provide absolute path, it says the location is outside of context. Any idea how to fix this? I am running on Mac OSX 10.

With the script above, I am getting the following error :

    `ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder6164655/Users/myid/.ssh/id_rsa: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it might be related to this bug [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25925)

The broken example is very similar to your path problem:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:14.04
COPY start.sh /start.sh

# comes back with: 
stat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/e89417ccaafbc91c3f930b56819427f83b3f2d3b3a246fbd6b48c9abcc7233f6/start.sh: no such file or directory
```

I'd try

- updating to the most recent docker
- restarting your docker engine