# How can I pass ssh credentials to the docker daemon on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, docker, ssh

I'd like to have a section like this in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
 services:
     thing:
          build: git@server.company.com/path/to/project.git
```

Then I'd like to build it with `docker-compose build thing`

But when I try that it fails with

```
ERROR: error fetching: fatal: 'git@server.company.com/path/to/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Presumably it's failing because it needs my ssh keys to access the repository and the docker daemon is running in a linux VM which doesn't have access to my keys.

How can I pass a ssh key, or an ssh agent socket to the docker daemon so it can access a private repository?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136389/using-ssh-keys-inside-docker-container
This answers your question.

Comment: I don't think it does.   This is about passing ssh creeds to access the docker file in the first place, not about accessing ssh keys inside a container