# Remote Containers - Can't use Git with SSH key

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

I'm developing an Angular app in a docker container set up with the extension. 
Is there a way to use my local id_rsa to fetch and push code to my gitlab repository? (it has been cloned via SSH on my host machine)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to push directly from the remote container, you would to have access to your SSH key from within said container.

See for example "[Using SSH keys inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64792148/6309)" which does mount your local SSH folder

```sh
docker run --rm \
   -v ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh \
   ...
```