# Pull from a git repo with ssh, using secrets in docker-compose

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, openssh

I'm trying to create a build setup using `docker-compose` which requires pulling npm packages from a private repository.

My setup looks like this:

```yaml
// docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  node:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
      - /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro
      - /etc/group:/etc/group:ro
      - /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts:ro
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      //- USER_UID=${USER_UID:-1000}
      //- USER_GID=${USER_GID:-1000}
    secrets:
      - user_private_ssh_key
      - user_public_ssh_key
      - ssh_config

secrets:
  user_private_ssh_key:
    file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  user_public_ssh_key:
    file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  ssh_config:
    file: ~/.ssh/config
```

```
# DOCKERFILE
FROM node:14

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-client
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/.ssh
RUN ln -s /run/secrets/user_private_ssh_key /home/node/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN ln -s /run/secrets/user_public_ssh_key /home/node/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
RUN ln -s /run/secrets/ssh_config /home/node/.ssh/config
RUN chown -R node:node /home/node/.ssh
# RUN chmod 600 /home/node/.ssh/*
# RUN chmod 644 /home/node/.ssh/config
RUN ls -la /home/node/.ssh
USER node:node

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY . /home/node/app
# if the next line works, the following will as well
RUN ssh -v git@git.example.com
# RUN yarn install --verbose

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

I can see that my secrets are being added to the container. Their content is correct as well.

What doesn't work is, that the `ssh_config` is not being read by `openssh-client`. So it connects to the wrong port (22) for the packages on `git.example.com`. The correct port in this case would be e.g. 3333.

```
// error message
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7, OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
debug1: Connecting to git.example.com [IP_ADDRESS] port 22.
```

What configuration am I missing for this to work?

Comment: I got this to run without secrets, using a passwordless private key in an image that is dropped afterwards, see [Using SSH keys inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136389/using-ssh-keys-inside-docker-container/66648529#66648529).