# Install node_modules from BitBucket in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, git, docker, docker-compose, bitbucket

I have installed a node module from BitBucket. It is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "some-module": "git+https://bitbucket.org/some-module.git"
}
```

However, when I build the Docker image with this Dockerfile,

```
FROM node:14.4.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./ .
```

I am failed to build because I have not provided the git credentials when building the image.

I don't want to save my git credentials in the package.json file but save it in the server. What type of credentials and how can I provide the credentials when building the image?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use ssh keys for this one, instead of the user credentials

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136389/using-ssh-keys-inside-docker-container)

Comment: Finally found the solution. We need to generate the SSH keys and  change `git+https` to `git+ssh`

Answer (score 1):

As altready mentioned you can use ssh url in your Package.json and configure the SSH keys on the environment where your Dockerfile is built.

Otherwise, you can also use a private package repository, such as [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=11007065731&gclid=Cj0KCQjwp86EBhD7ARIsAFkgakg6as3sJQ_6wSpvjBZpr_EbAmKM9E2CfbR2j5fF3popJ1R8XWZ-0MgaAlC7EALw_wcB) or [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products/repository-pro), publish your library package on this repo, then install it via npm, configure npm to use your private repository instead of npm public.

https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-2-npm-packages