# How to pass git/ssh credentials to a docker image run from Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-groovy

I have a pretty basic Jenkinsfile:

```
docker.image('MY_IMAGE').inside {
  sh '/bin/my-command my-args'
}
```

This is a Pipeline script run in a Groovy sandbox. `my-command` will run `git clone`, and `MY_IMAGE` contains `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

This works at the moment but including `id_rsa` in the image is bad security practice.

It would be better if the ssh keys (or other authentication credentials) lived in the Jenkins configuration. (It would also be ideal if known_hosts was in the Jenkins configuration, but that's a lower priority.)

I have Jenkins 2.150.1, what's the right way to set this up?

Comment: how about `cat some_config > the id_rsa_file`? or, as a walkaround, use git token instead(as it can be readonly)?

Comment: Where would the `cat` expression live? Where would `some_config` live? I'm unfamiliar with Jenkins

Comment: i'm not familiar with jenkins, either -_-. but some experience with gitlab ci. there must be some where to config the file content, and then jenkins can run shell command right? so `docker run --env from_someconfig dockername bash -c 'echo env_var' > id_rsa` ?

Comment: Related: [Using SSH keys inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18136389/16586783)

Answer (score 0):

If you store your SSH keys as a [Jenkins credential](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/), something like this should work:

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: '<credential ID here>', keyFileVariable: 'KEY_FILE_PATH')]) {
    docker.image('MY_IMAGE').inside {
        sh 'cp $KEY_FILE_PATH ~/.ssh/id_rsa'
        sh '/bin/my-command my-args'
    }
}
```

The [`withCredentials(...)`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/#withcredentials-bind-credentials-to-variables) pipeline step will fetch the SSH key and store it in a temporary directory accessible to your job (usually `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<job path>@tmp`.) This directory will be automatically mounted in your container as a volume, under the same path.

Since the `KEY_FILE_PATH` environment variable will also be passed to your image, it can be referenced however you like, like copying it to `~/.ssh/id_rsa` in the above example.