# Accessing and using ssh keys from host machine from docker container using ssh sockets in a secure way

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, containers, ssh-agent

I am trying to add possibility to use host machine ssh keys to fetch private repositories. However, I haven't been successful to do so in a secure manner. I don't want to copy ssh key's at build time, use root inside container, set uid and gid to match the user on the host machine because all this pose security risks. The way I am trying to go is using ssh socket forwarding. I am successful with doing so, however, it requires to use it with sudo which is unacceptable for me. I am trying to do so for ages and getting more fed up with cause I am able to find plenty of solutions, but non of them are following good practices.

The command I am running the container:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(dirname $SSH_AUTH_SOCK):/home/slomka/ssh-agent/ -e      SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/slomka/ssh-agent/$(basename $SSH_AUTH_SOCK) -v ~/.ssh/:/home/slomka/.ssh example-container
```

then I am running:

```
socat -dddd UNIX-LISTEN:/home/slomka/.ssh/socket,fork,user=slomka,group=build,mode=777 \
UNIX-CONNECT:/home/slomka/ssh-agent/
```

and then I set:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/slomka/.ssh/socket
```

(I tried with setting owner and group of /ssh-agent dir and its content to the ones used in container)

And then I get connection refused:

```
2023/09/21 09:26:31 socat[196] I close(5)
2023/09/21 09:26:31 socat[196] N opening connection to AF=1 "/home/slomka/ssh-agent/"
2023/09/21 09:26:31 socat[196] I socket(1, 1, 0) -> 5
2023/09/21 09:26:31 socat[196] E connect(5, AF=1 "/home/slomka/ssh-agent/", 25): Connection refused
2023/09/21 09:26:31 socat[196] N exit(1)
2023/09/21 09:26:31 socat[196] I shutdown(6, 2)
2023/09/21 09:26:31 socat[196] I shutdown(5, 2)
2023/09/21 09:26:31 socat[165] N childdied(): handling signal 17
2023/09/21 09:26:31 socat[165] I childdied(signum=17)
2023/09/21 09:26:31 socat[165] I childdied(17): cannot identify child 196
2023/09/21 09:26:31 socat[165] I waitpid(): child 196 exited with status 1
2023/09/21 09:26:31 socat[165] I waitpid(-1, {}, WNOHANG): No child processes
2023/09/21 09:26:31 socat[165] I childdied() finished
```

Comment: Why do you need ssh credentials while you're running the image?  [Using SSH keys inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136389/using-ssh-keys-inside-docker-container) seems to cover this area pretty well, does its answers cover your case as well?

Comment: The issue is that the solutions with passing ssh as a volume (-v ~/.ssh ...) and using ssh-agent have one flaw they work but only in root environemnt, when used with custom user within container the only thing I get is "Permission denied" everywhere. That's what I am trying to find a solution for.

Comment: Do you run `socat` on host or in the container ?

Comment: You want to connect to a UNIX domain socket but you just specify directory /home/slomka/ssh-agent/ , failure is inevitable

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.

I think you mix up containers with virtual machines and what you really need is a VM.

A container is not a VM and shouldn't be treated as such, even if you can exec into the container and get a shell and do stuff like you would do in a baremetal/vm OS.

A container is "just" a process (and it's child processes) running natively in a separated area on the host with the help of the linux namespaces.

So your container starts from an image and you build your own image and start the container and let it do it's sole purpose, to run that one process that it is supposed to run.

For example create this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim as node

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    tini \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /home/node/app    

COPY index.js index.js

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/tini", "--" ]

CMD ["node","index.js"]
```

put index.js with this content into the same directory as the Dockerfile is:

```
console.log("Hello Node Starting!");

setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Hello Node Running!");
}, 1000);
```

Build the image:

`docker build . --progress=plain -f Dockerfile -t hello-node:1.0.0`

Start a container from the image with rm flag so the container is removed when you stop it with ctrl+c

`docker run --rm hello-node:1.0.0`
you can see the output of the container in your terminal:

```
$ docker run --rm hello-node:1.0.0
Hello Node Starting!
Hello Node Running!
Hello Node Running!
Hello Node Running!
Hello Node Running!
^C%
```

Or you can make it run in the background (-d or --detach flag) with `docker run -d --name hello-node-container hello-node:1.0.0` with naming it hello-node-container and get it's logs with `docker logs hello-node-container -f`

You don't want to ever ssh into a container and do stuff there because they are - by design - ephemeral and must be treated so. So if you want to modify your container you need to update the image (with modifying the Dockerfile and building a new image) stop the old container and start the new container from the new image.

You can however `docker exec` into a running container with `docker exec -it hello-node-container bash` and do stuff there but this is only to debug and investigate problems and when you know what the problem is you modify Dockerfile, create new image, stop bad container, start new container from new image.

Comment: Let me explain what I would like to do in the container. To be honest it does a one single thing, but this single thing is complex underneath. What I need to do is to fetch Yocto project(Build system for creating a custom Linux distro) with dozens of proprietary repos which are on private git server. The container should act as an isolated place with specific set of tools and configurations. The output is the build artifacts. Docker container gives the flexibility where vm doesn't because it should be  easily customizable by other users of the container.

Comment: To be more precise with my previous comment the fetching is spited into 3 stages - first the main repo is downloaded that repo tool fetches more or less a 20 repositories which during build process download another dozens of repos.That's the reason I need ssh working during build time in docker.

Comment: @SebastianSłomka this is not what Docker images and containers are for. Your problem is a CI/CD problem and not a containerization problem. So what you need is a CI/CD tool like gitlab/github/bitbucket/jenkins where you can build your artifacts, with stages and jobs: 1st stage is get all the git repos into working dir, 2nd stage is the build with Yocto, 3rd stage is the publish artifact to a repository. With these cicd tools you can store secrets (ssh keys, passwords) that the jobs can then use.

Answer (score 0):

This command start a container using `ubuntu` image by
passing ssh keys in ssh-agent :

```
docker run -it --rm -v $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:$SSH_AUTH_SOCK\
        -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK ubuntu\
        bash -c 'apt-get update; apt-get install -y openssh-client;
                 echo -e "\nPrivate keys in ssh-agent:";
                 ssh-add -l; exec bash'
```