# bashrc not loading until run bash command

Tags: linux, bash

I am running freshly installed Arch Linux. When I log into a user (running bash) and try to use an alias from .bashrc, it gives me the 'command not found' error. But, if I reenter bash via the 'bash' command, the command works just fine.

Yes, I am already in bash.

env initially:

```
SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
```

env after running bash, it remains:

```
SHELL=/usr/bin/bash
```

So I'm not quite sure where the problem is.

Comment: Well its actually a function: function cl(){cd $@; ls}

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/415444/208997

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Read the INVOCATION section from "bash(1)" for full details (that's the man page for bash; use `man bash`). Your first shell upon logging in is a "login shell", which means that the `.bashrc` file is not sourced. Your second invocation creates an interactive shell, where `.bashrc` is sourced.

If you always want the content of your `.bashrc` file processed, you can add the following lines to your `.bash_profile` file, creating that file if it does not already exist:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Per its man page, bash "[...] looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable." Conventions and policies of your local system will determine which, if any, of these files already exist.

A word of caution: be aware that creating a new `.bash_profile` in your home directory could have the unintended side-effect of preventing the reading and executing of commands in a `.bash_login` or `.profile` file already present, changing further the behavior of subsequent logins.

Comment: And create '~/.bash_login' file if not yet here

Comment: or use `~/.profile` for any Bourne-compatible login shells. (bash)

Comment: @Qwerty: if you maintain your environment such that ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bash_login do not exist, using ~/.profile works. From a version 4.2 bash man page: "When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable."

Comment: Thanks for the information guys, just started using AIX and finding it very difficult that the bashrc file is not getting loaded automatically, their is no /etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile scripts present in the machine but now created one as @jean Davy said. your answers are just to the point. Big cheers..

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at your `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.bash_profile` files?

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot about that. Not used to having to set up stuff thanks to Ubuntu.