# setting ssh-agent env vars

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, ssh-agent

A manual workaround has been provided for this issue in:

[Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent)

However why is ssh-agent not setting the correct environmental variables? and how can they be set permanently?