# git isn't using rsa keys

Tags: git, authentication, git-push

I'm not sure why this is happening.  I've followed the instructions [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) for setting up a user, named 'git', on my Linux machine.  I have set up a few repositories as instructed there.  I have generated RSA keys and copied/appended the `id_rsa.pub` key to `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

In one case, I'm using `cygwin` and generated the ssh keys.  I use these same keys through cygwin to log into this Linux machine all the time using a different user id.

However, I cannot do a `git push origin master` as shown in that link without being prompted for the git user's password.  What am I missing?

Comment: `I use these same keys through cygwin to log into this Linux machine all the time using a different user id` How do you log into another user account, with ssh keys of `git` user?

Comment: do `ssh-add -l` to show your currently loaded keys. you probably don't have them loaded or agent forwarded

Comment: Possibly related: [Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/17848593#17848593).

Comment: @mu無 I may not have been clear enough.  I don't use the keys of the git user.  I have cygwin installed.  I generated an RSA pair and use that to log into this same linux machine regularly.  The account I normally use is different from my windows account name, but I'm still able to log in.  I placed my id_rsa.pub key in the .ssh/authorized_keys file of the git user, but when I log in, it still prompts me for the password.

Comment: @UpAndAdam I will definitely check into this one on Monday