# ssh-agent isn't creating in CMD

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I used the following command in CMD:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

And the output is:

> 'eval' is not recognized as an internal or external, operable program
>   or batch file.

Looking for the solution in CMD, it works fine in gitbash

Comment: Where are you typing this, exactly?

Comment: typing in the command prompt with RoR. What do you mean by 'duplicate'?

Comment: Please explain what terminal shell and OS you are using. Are you actually trying to use this from within interactive Ruby (`irb`)? Or a Windows command shell?

Comment: How did you install Git? I don't think Ruby on Rails comes with its own command prompt. What happens when you type just `ssh-agent`? Do you even have that available? If not, you'll either have to install it, or you can try install [msysgit](http://git-scm.com/), which already comes with it.

Comment: Guys I don't think its a duplicate. I tried that solution but it require 'eval', which I cannot use. I'm on a Win 7, cygwin (i think), and a whole lotta ignorance as I'm traversing M.Hartl's RoR tutorial. (Thanks ruby.railstutorial.org). Anything else ? Could it be a Heroku issue?

Comment: @kurriking are you sure that you're using [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)? I have cygwin too, and it has both `eval` and `exec`. Did you forget the backticks?

Comment: use gitbash for this .. agent primary id is created without creating any error

Answer (score 1):

There are other commands that you can try to start the `ssh-agent`, depending on your shell and operating system. Here is an another command that you could try (from the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17846529/456814)):

```
exec ssh-agent bash
```

Comment: Same thing with 'exec'. It is not recognized as a command et al.

Comment: same problem, have you managed to solve it?

Comment: Could not solve it nor find a solution in cmd/windows 10, works perfectly in git-bash as stated in the question.