# Git Bash: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm new to Github and Generating SSH Keys look a neccessity. And was informed by my boss about this, so I need to comply.

I successfully created SSH Key but when I'm going to add it to the ssh-agent

this is what happens

What seems to be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 219, accepted):

It seems you need to run `ssh-agent` before using it:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

That question was answered in this topic: [Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent)

Comment: Thanks! what worked for me is `exec ssh-agent bash` then `eval ssh-agent -s` then  `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. After following these steps nor the 'Could not open a connection' steps (git bash on windows).

Comment: @hikki I don't understand why all this mumbo jumbo is needed, but your approach finally worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: My case on FreeBSD v10: Kritana solution did not work, but @leipz solution did. Thanks you.

Comment: It is worth noting that `eval \`ssh-agent -s\` ` are the right apostrophes. Using `eval  'ssh-agent -s' ` or `eval "ssh-agent -s" ` will not work.

Comment: Thank you @leipzy! For some wild reason ssh-agent was running with a PID, but your steps helped me restart and then I was able to add a key.

Comment: The top comment actually worked

Answer (score 53):

I checked all the solutions on this post and the post that @kenorb referenced above, and I did not find any solution that worked for me.

I am using Git 1.9.5 Preview on Windows 7 with the following configuration:
- Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt
- Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style line endings

I used the '**Git Bash**' console for everything... And *all was well until I tried to install the SSH keys*. GitHub's documentation says to do the following *(don't run these commands until you finish reading the post)*:

> **Ensure ssh-agent is enabled:**
>
> If you are using Git Bash, turn on ssh-agent:
>
> ```
> # start the ssh-agent in the background
> ssh-agent -s
> # Agent pid 59566
> ```
>
> If you are using another terminal prompt, such as msysgit, turn on ssh-agent:
>
> ```
> # start the ssh-agent in the background
> eval $(ssh-agent -s)
> # Agent pid 59566
> ```

Now of course I missed the fact that you were supposed to do one or the other. So, I ran these commands multiple times because the later `ssh-add` command was failing, so I returned to this step, and continued to retry over and over.

***This results in 1 Windows 'ssh-agent' process being created every single time you run these commands (notice the new PID every time you enter those commands?)***

So, `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Del` and hit `End Process` to stop each '**ssh-agent.exe**' process.

Now that all the messed up stuff from the failed attempts is cleaned up, I will tell you how to get it working...

### In '**Git Bash**':

Start the '**ssh-agent.exe**' process

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

And install the SSH keys

```
ssh-add "C:\Users\MyName\.ssh\id_rsa"
```

*** Adjust the path above with your username, and make sure that the location of the*** **/.ssh** ***directory is in the correct place. I think you choose this location during the Git installation? Maybe not...***

The part I was doing wrong before I figured this out was I was not using quotes around the '**ssh-add**' location. The above is how it needs to be entered on Windows.

Comment: I am not sure about using `"C:\Path\To"` in Git-Bash under windows. I remember a while back I received errors when using typical windows paths. You can also use `ssh-add /c/Users/YourName/.ssh/id_rsa`. - I thank you for this answer though. Following the Git docs resulted in many ssh agents running. After killing them, and using the alternate eval method, this worked perfect.

Comment: I didn't realize that there was another way to specify a path in Windows. Good to know. You are welcome, just hope it saves everyone the headache I endured.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Del and hit End Process to stop each 'ssh-agent.exe' step was all what I needed!

Comment: @FeritBuyukkececi - Glad to hear you were able to get up and running!

Comment: This worked for me, but only temporary. Is there a trick that it will always work? This is kinda annoying :/

Comment: @Isengo this worked permanently for me. I am unsure why it wouldn't for you. Maybe something is preventing the SSH Agent from running after you restart your machine?

Comment: this needs to be moved to best answer

Comment: @Isengo - There may be something else wrong if this didn't resolve your issue permanently...

Comment: @ASignor - Thank you for the props! Glad this helped you...

Comment: @derekmx271 thanks for checking. I am using Ubuntu now - so I am good :)

Comment: Awesome, it made the trick forme

Comment: `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` worked for me - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 23):

On Windows, you can use **Run** with one of the below commands.

*For 32-Bit:*

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\start-ssh-agent.cmd"

*For-64 Bit:*

> "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\start-ssh-agent.cmd"

Comment: Needs to be wrapped with double quotes.

Comment: I tried almost EVERYTHING that was suggested. Nothing worked besides this one. I guess every person can have a different problem with the same msgs.

Comment: Or start OpenSSH Authentication Agent in Services then run `ssh-agent ssh-add "C:\Users\<username>\.ssh\id_rsa"`

Answer (score 17):

**Situation: MVS2017 App - Using 'Git Bash' on Windows 10 - Trying to connect to a BitBucket repository.**

To be clear, when you install Git for Windows (https://git-scm.com/download/win), it comes with an utility called Git Bash.

[image]

So, I am in 'Git Bash', as follows:

```
Mike@DUBLIN MINGW64 ~/source/repos/DoubleIrish (master)
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:Guiness/DoubleIrish.git
$ git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:Guiness/DoubleIrish.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:Guiness/DoubleIrish.git (push)
Mike@DUBLIN MINGW64 ~/source/repos/DoubleIrish (master)
$ git push -u origin master
[...]
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Is the private key set up?

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018
$ ls -a ~/.ssh
./  ../  known_hosts
```

I can see that, at this point, my *private key file* (`id_rsa`) is missing. So I add it:
(note: generating a pair of private-public keys is out of scope of my reply, but
I can say that in Linux, you can use `ssh-keygen` for that.)

```
$ ls -a ~/.ssh
./  ../  id_rsa  known_hosts
```

OK, let's proceed:

```
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-KhQwFLAgWGYC/agent.18320; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=17996; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 17996;

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

To solve this, I run:

```
$ ssh-agent bash
```

And then, again:

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /c/Users/Mike.CORP/.ssh/id_rsa (/c/Users/Mike.CORP/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

It worked for me. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the problem as well.

After I typed 
$ eval 'ssh-agent -s'
followed by
$ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

I got the same complain: "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent". Then I realize there are two different kind of quotation on my computer's keyboard. So I tried the one at the same position as "~":
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

And bang it worked.

Comment: I can't believe I struggle to find this for a whole day. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to improve on the accepted answer

Downsides of using `.bashrc` with `eval ssh-agent -s`:

1. Every git-bash will have it's own ssh-agent.exe process
2. SSH key should be manually added every time you open git-bash

Here is my `.bashrc` that will eradicate above downsides

Put this `.bashrc` into your home directory (Windows 10: `C:\Users\[username]\.bashrc`) and it will be executed every time a new git-bash is opened
and `ssh-add` will be working as a first class citizen

Read #comments to understand how it works

```
# Env vars used
# SSH_AUTH_SOCK - ssh-agent socket, should be set for ssh-add or git to be able to connect
# SSH_AGENT_PID - ssh-agent process id, should be set in order to check that it is running
# SSH_AGENT_ENV - env file path to share variable between instances of git-bash
SSH_AGENT_ENV=~/ssh-agent.env
# import env file and supress error message if it does not exist
. $SSH_AGENT_ENV 2> /dev/null

# if we know that ssh-agent was launched before ($SSH_AGENT_PID is set) and process with that pid is running 
if [ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ] && ps -p $SSH_AGENT_PID > /dev/null 
then
  # we don't need to do anything, ssh-add and git will properly connect since we've imported env variables required
  echo "Connected to ssh-agent"
else   
  # start ssh-agent and save required vars for sharing in $SSH_AGENT_ENV file
  eval $(ssh-agent) > /dev/null
  echo export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=\"$SSH_AUTH_SOCK\" > $SSH_AGENT_ENV
  echo export SSH_AGENT_PID=$SSH_AGENT_PID >> $SSH_AGENT_ENV
  echo "Started ssh-agent"
fi
```

Also this script uses a little trick to ensure that provided environment variables are shared between git-bash instances by saving them into an `.env` file.

Answer (score -2):

above solution doesn't work for me for unknown reason. below is my workaround which was worked successfully.

1) **DO NOT** generate a new ssh key by using command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C"xxx@xx.com"`,  you can delete existing SSH keys.

2) but use Git GUI, -> "Help" -> "Show ssh key" -> "Generate key",  the key will saved to ssh automatically and no need to use `ssh-add` anymore.

Comment: your advise is conflicting the OP question with irrelevant topics ... how you generate the ssh key pair is orthogonal to the issue at hand