# How to use SSH key in a Windows Container

Tags: git, docker, ssh

I have created a windows container that includes a Git client and I am able to clone and checkout from our Bitbucket server using HTTP. This means I need to provide username and password for every transaction with Git.
I am now wanting to rather use SSH. So I have generated an SSH key using ssh-keygen and have added the public key to my user account in Bitbucket and on my local PC I am able to transact with Bitbucket successfully as I loaded my key using Pageant.

Within the container I am struggling to get this to work.
I found some info [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_sharing-git-credentials-with-your-container) which I included in my Dockerfile - specifically the commands Set-Service, Start-Service and Get-Service.
This works up to a point, this line `RUN printf "${SSH_KEY_PASSPHRASE}" | ssh-add C:\Users\Jenkins\.ssh\id_rsa` fails to build - it doesn't recognize `printf`. I have tried to replace it with `echo` but also fails.

If I remove this line from my Dockerfile I can build and run this container; I then tried go into it with a powershell session and tried to run `ssh-add C:\Users\Jenkins\.ssh\id_rsa` manually but I get response `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`
If I run `Get-Service ssh-agent` it reports that ssh-agent is running.

So my questions are as follows:

1. Why is the `ssh-add` command not working?
2. How to I add my ssh key within this container?
3. When I get the `ssh-add` command to work, how do I specify the passphrase in the Dockerfile?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore
ARG SSH_KEY_PASSPHRASE

COPY .\files\Git-2.18.0-64-bit.exe      C:\installers\git-installer.exe
COPY .\files\Git-2.18.0-64-bit.inf      C:\installers\git-installer-script.inf
RUN powershell -Command `
  # Install Git ; `
  Start-Process -filepath C:\installers\git-installer.exe -passthru -wait -argumentlist "/LOADINF=C:\installers\git-installer-script.inf","/VERYSILENT","/NORESTART" ; `
Remove-Item C:\installers\ -Force -Recurse;

RUN powershell -Command `
  net user /add Jenkins; `
  net localgroup Administrators Jenkins /add;
USER Jenkins
RUN powershell -Command `
  mkdir ~\.ssh;

COPY .\id_rsa  C:\Users\Jenkins\.ssh\id_rsa

RUN powershell -Command `
  # Make sure you're running as an Administrator `
  Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic; `
  Start-Service ssh-agent; `
  Get-Service ssh-agent; 

# This doesn't work and I don't know how to do this
RUN  printf "${SSH_KEY_PASSPHRASE}" | ssh-add C:\Users\Jenkins\.ssh\id_rsa
```

---

**Edit 1**

I have now discovered that if run this container (without the `ssh-add` command in the dockerfile) and then run a git clone using the ssh URL, it states that the authenticity of the bitbucket host can't be established, do you want to continue connecting? I enter "yes" and it then "*permanently adds my bit bucket host to the list of known hosts*" before asking for the passphrase for key 'c/Users/Jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa'.

Once I enter the passphrase it successfully clones the repo.
This result surprises me and results in a new question:

- How does it know about the ssh key in c/Users/Jenkins/.ssh if I haven't added it yet? I'm clearly missing some understanding somewhere.

---

**Edit 2**

I have played around with my Dockerfile and found that the line
`RUN powershell -Command mkdir ~\.ssh` seems to be important in some way.
If I remove this line and run the container, I can see that my key is present in `C:\Users\Jenkins\.ssh\` but if I run `ssh-add .\Users\Jenkins\.ssh\id_rsa` it fails with `Permissions for id_rsa are too open`.
If I include the `mkdir` line there is no obvious difference to me but the `ssh-add` command seems to work and reports `Identity added: .\Users\Jenkins\.ssh\id_rsa (<my company domain>+<my windows username@PC name>)`.

If I don't manually create the .ssh folder it still seems to be implicitly created during the `COPY` command but the `ssh-add` fails. What is going on here?

Next I included the `ssh-add` command into my Dockerfile and rebuilt it and could see that the key was added - it reports `Identity added: .\Users\Jenkins\.ssh\id_rsa`.

At this stage I am not able to interact with Git as the path was not setup, so I modified my Dockerfile to setup the path by adding the following lines to the command where I install Git;

```
${env:PATH} = 'C:\Git\bin;C:\Git\usr\bin;C:\Git\mingw64\bin;' + $env:PATH;
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', ${env:PATH}, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine);
```

Now when I build the image the ssh-add command fails with "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."
I ran `Get-Service ssh-agent` which reports that it is running.

So somehow the inclusion of Git into the path has resulted in a difference regarding the `ssh-add` command.
What is happening here?
How do I resolve this?

I also recreated the key without a passphrase so have removed the need to enter a passphrase during the docker build and I specified the version of windows.

Here is my updated Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1903

# Install Git
COPY .\files\Git-2.18.0-64-bit.exe      C:\installers\git-installer.exe
COPY .\files\Git-2.18.0-64-bit.inf      C:\installers\git-installer-script.inf
RUN powershell -Command `
  Start-Process -filepath C:\installers\git-installer.exe -passthru -wait -argumentlist "/LOADINF=C:\installers\git-installer-script.inf","/VERYSILENT","/NORESTART" ; `
  Remove-Item C:\installers\ -Force -Recurse; `
  # Set the path to include Git folders - not listed in my original post `
  ${env:PATH} = 'C:\Git\bin;C:\Git\usr\bin;C:\Git\mingw64\bin;' + $env:PATH; `
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', ${env:PATH}, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine);

# Create a Jenkins user with admin permissions
RUN powershell -Command `
  net user /add Jenkins; `
  net localgroup Administrators Jenkins /add;
  USER Jenkins
# The presence or absence of this mkdir command affects ssh-add for some reason
RUN powershell -Command `
  mkdir ~\.ssh;

# This key was created without a passphrase
COPY .\id_rsa  C:\Users\Jenkins\.ssh\id_rsa

RUN powershell -Command `
  # Make sure you're running as an Administrator `
  Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic; `
  Start-Service ssh-agent; `
  Get-Service ssh-agent; `
  ssh-add .\Users\Jenkins\.ssh\id_rsa;
```

---

**Edit 3**

Thanks to information I found [here](https://coderwall.com/p/rdi_wq/fix-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent-when-using-ssh-add) I it seems that the inability to run `ssh-add` successfully was due to the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable not being set.
Running `ssh-agent` provides the data needed to set this environment variable and in Linux you could run `eval $(ssh-agent)` but powershell in windows doesn't recognize the `eval` command. At this stage I tried commenting out the `ssh-add` command from my last dockerfile and then inside the container I manually ran the `ssh-agent` command and set the environment variable using `$Env:SSH_AUTH_SOCK = "<value returned from ssh-agent>"` which succeeded and if I run `Get-ChildItem Env:` I see this new environment variable listed.

I then tried to run a `git clone ssh://git@mybitbucketurl/myrepo.git` which reported that "the authenticity of host mybitbucketurl (xx.yy.zz.aa:port) can't be established. Are you sure you want to continue (yes/no)?"
I entered "yes" and it "Permanently added mybitbucketurl:port,[xx.yy.zz.aa]:port (RSA) to the list of known hosts" and then cloned my repository.

I thought I had this cracked now and thought I just needed to work out how to do the `eval` command equivalent in powershell. While I was searching for clues on how to do this I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154816/git-bash-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent) with an answer that listed this command:
`ssh-agent ssh-add C:\Users\<username>\.ssh\id_rsa`.
I tried running this manually inside my container and it reported that the identity was added, however when I tried to run a `git clone` it first add the URL to the list of known hosts and then failed with "fatal: could not read from remote repository".
Running `Get-ChildItem Env:` showed that the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable is not set so I guess that running it like this is an isolated session of sorts although I don't really know what is happening with this command.

So from here it looks like I need to work out how to run the `ssh-agent` command and use its result in powershell to setup the environment variable permanently.
Once I have got that working I need to work out how to add my Git host URL to the list of known hosts.

---

**Edit 4**

The crux of my issue seems to be the difference between the build-time and run-time of my docker image and specifically of what I am hoping to achieve with `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`.
If I setup my image to include the ssh key and then run it, I am able to manually do the following (note that I've switched from powershell to bash):

```
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK

$ eval $(ssh-agent)
Agent pid 2036
$ sh-add Users/Jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: Users/Jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-qCM264wFqpqq/agent.1748
```

So from this I can see that at run-time in the container it does what I want it to.
However if I try and run these commands at build-time from the Dockerfile things do not work as I would hope.
After some thought I suspect that the `eval $(ssh-agent)` command probably runs but the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable is not retained within the image's layer and when the container is run ssh-agent will not be running, something probably needs to launch it.

What is the right way to do this:

1. Do I try to get these commands to run during startup of the container via a startup script?
2. Is there a way to still do this at build time (i.e. from the Dockerfile) - to achieve this I would manually need to set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable but this seems to be different every time you run `ssh-agent` - is this worth pursuing?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much for doing all of this work and documenting your progress.
I also tried many things on my side and I finally got something working.

I added the file known_hosts that you can find inside the .ssh directory.
This is working for me:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

RUN powershell -Command \
    mkdir C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\.ssh
COPY ["./id_ed25519", "./Users/ContainerAdministrator/.ssh/"]
COPY ["./known_hosts", "./Users/ContainerAdministrator/.ssh/"]

RUN powershell -Command \
    Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic ; \
    Start-Service ssh-agent ; \
    ssh-add .\Users\ContainerAdministrator\.ssh\id_ed25519 ; \
    git clone <your repo> ; \
    Remove-Item C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\.ssh -Force -Recurse
```