# gpg decryption fails with no secret key error

Tags: unix, encryption, public-key-encryption, gnupg

I have a gpg .key file that is used as passphrase for decrypting a .dat.pgp file. The encrypted .data.pgp file gets successfully decrypted on one server with same .key file using following command

```
cat xxx_gpg.key | /usr/bin/gpg --batch --quiet -o xxx.dat --passphrase-fd O -d xxx.dat.pgp
```

But, when I move same key to another server xxx_gpg.key and run same above command, I get following error -

```
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

EDIT:

I find that `gpg --list-secret-keys` returns some data on server where it works but no results are returned for other server.

How can we configure secret key

Comment: Exact same version of gpg on each machine?

Comment: same gpg version on both places - 2.0.14

Comment: hmmm. Apparently `--passphrase-fd` only reads the "first line", do those look identical on each system? Maybe a different shell is converting or pipe-ing them differently? Just saw a case where backslashes were being "eaten" by read...

Comment: passphrase is same everywhere, only difference i found is what I also edited in post that gpg --list-secret-keys  lists differently

Comment: I had thought you were using "conventional" encryption, should've thought of the public/private key encryption much earlier but got mixed up with the "keyfile" and "secret key" too. I'll post a few options/ideas

Comment: This happens with gpg2.1.5 encrypted file with ssb subkey only (sec key works fine), gpg2.1.5 cannot decrypt its own output, but gpg1.4 is able to decrypt the same data. On win7.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like the secret key isn't on the other machine, so even with the right passphrase (read from a file) it wouldn't work.

These options should work, to

- Either copy the keyrings (maybe only secret keyring required, but public ring is public anyway) over to the other machine
- Or export the secret key & then import it on the other machine

A few useful looking options from `man gpg`:

> `--export`
>   Either export all keys from all keyrings (default keyrings and  those
>                 registered  via  option `--keyring`), or if at least one name is given,
>                 those of the given name. The new keyring is written to STDOUT  or  to
>                 the  file  given  with  option `--output`. Use together with `--armor` to
>                 mail those keys.
>
> `--export-secret-keys`
>                Same as `--export`, but exports the secret keys instead.
>
> `--import`
>   `--fast-import`
>                Import/merge keys. This adds the given keys to the keyring. The  fast
>                 version is currently just a synonym.

And maybe

> `--keyring file`
>                Add file to the current list of keyrings. If file begins with a tilde
>                 and a slash, these are replaced by the $HOME directory. If the  file‐
>                 name  does not contain a slash, it is assumed to be in the GnuPG home
>                 directory ("~/.gnupg" if --homedir or $GNUPGHOME is not used).
>
> Note that this adds a keyring to the current list. If the  intent  is
>                 to  use  the  specified keyring alone, use `--keyring` along with `--no-default-keyring`.
>
> `--secret-keyring file`
>                Same as `--keyring` but for the secret keyrings.

Comment: Short version: 
# Import keys from another machine:
gpg --export ${ID} > public.key
gpg --export-secret-key ${ID} > private.key
# copy these files to another machine and there
gpg --import public.key
gpg --import private.key
# from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184947/how-to-import-secret-gpg-key-copied-from-one-machine-to-another

Comment: The above is precisely what I tried and what lead me to the error message that OP posted.

Comment: @aioobe The correct (secret) key must not be getting to, or getting seen by the other gpg. Do you mean you tried YaroslavNikitenko's commands? I haven't tested them but they *look* good, as long as `$ID` is right. I'd try `--output` instead but shouldn't matter. Exporting the secret key then importing it *should* work, does it show up in `--list-keys` (-k or -K)? Or copying the whole keyring file(s) then using `--keyring` definitely should... I've had trouble with gpg-agent's not reading passphrases before even with `--passphrase-file`, or replace `--quiet` & `--batch` with some `-v` 's

Comment: I did the `--export` / `--import` thing. The problem turned out to be the fact that we used `gpg` instead of `gpg2` on the "receiving" (`--import`) machine. Can't say why. They should be compatible, but it seems there are cases where they're not.

Comment: That's disappointing, hopefully it's just a minor bug that gets fixed quickly, backward compatibility is a big plus

Answer (score 53):

I just ran into this issue, on the gpg CLI in Arch Linux.  I needed to kill the existing "gpg-agent" process, then everything was back to normal (a new gpg-agent should auto-launch when you invoke the gpg command, again; ...).

- Edit 1: if the process fails to reload (e.g. within a minute), execute `gpg-agent` in a terminal and/or reboot ...

---

- Edit 2 [2024-02-19]: if after doing *that* you later encounter the "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent" error, try also (note backticks)

  ```
   eval `ssh-agent`
  ```

  per

  - [Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent)
  - https://gist.github.com/mvneves/a6a69a53f039b3755900

i.e.

```
gpg-agent
ssh-agent
ssh-add <your id_rsa public GPG key>
```

Explanation:

(a) The `gpg-agent` should enable you to use your GPG key.

(b) `ssh-agent` is needed for SSH authentication (launched with the `eval` command above, if needed - or simply `ssh-agent`).

(c) With my Arch Linux installation, it appears that a recent updates introduced the authentication issue, where applications needing SSH are not seeing the gpg server / daemon - hence authentication error messages.

Example: I've been using the Krusader file manager to connect to my VPS via a sFTP over a SSH connection (requires local host `gpg-agent`, `ssh-agent` daemons). Now, all of a sudden Krusader is reporting an authentication error. As a workaround in a terminal I issued the commands above, then in the same terminal launched Krusader (`krusader &`), which was them able to complete the sFTP connection to my VPS.

Comment: This was precisely my problem, and fix - i have been using gpg for a while without the agent, apparently it's now enabled by default?  Perhaps in ubuntu 17.04, which i am now (accidentally) running.  :-)  I guess it's still buggy.

Comment: Same issue and fix for me on macOS. A previous decryption went somehow awry which somehow caused the above errors.

Comment: ... just to add, on macOS, killing the `gpg-agent` works with `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`; no need to restart the agent specifically.

Comment: For me my terminal was too small. Making it bigger so there's room to type the passphrase within the gpg fixed it for me. This gets annoying really fast. I believe there's a way to save the passphrase somewhere. But it would be nice if there was an interface for smaller terminal screens rather than just causing the command to fail...

Answer (score 29):

I was trying to use [aws-vault](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault) which uses [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) and [gnugp2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gnupg2) (gpg2). I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 running in WSL2.

I tried all the solutions above, and eventually, I had to do one more thing -

```sh
$ rm ~/.gnupg/S.*                    # remove cache
$ gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye # restart gpg agent
$ export GPG_TTY=$(tty)              # prompt for password
# ^ This last line should be added to your ~/.bashrc file
```

The source of this solution is from some [blog-post in Japanese](https://hackers-high.com/aws/aws-vault-on-linux/), luckily there's Google Translate :)

Comment: Works also for Ubuntu 18.04 running in WSL2

Comment: Also worked for macOS

Answer (score 18):

This error will arise when using the utility `pass` *if the terminal window is too small!*

Just make the terminal window a few lines taller.

Very confusing.

**EXPLANATION FOR SKEPTICS.** This is a problem when using the curses version of pinentry, as described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/1019pn/making_gpg2_pinentry_work_on_a_really_small_screen/c69l6yd/): "because of the way they draw the dialog with curses, pinentry-curses only works on terminals which are greater than 10 lines tall"

Comment: I think you made a valid point. Neglecting this could lead to unnecessary confusion. So I voted you up again :)

Comment: oh my god, i would never thought that could be an issue. this totally solved my problem

Comment: You deserve a million upvotes.  I had this exact problem.  I googled and found your answer.  I was able to solve the problem with minimal fuss.

Comment: Same if you su - yourUser and then you try to use /usr/bin/pass, yourUser don't own tty, it won't work

Answer (score 8):

You can also sometimes get this error if you try to decrypt a secret while `su`-ed to a different user on a system with GPG 2.x installed.  [This bug has been reported against RHEL 6](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=659512) but there is no fix available; apparently this is due to some design decisions in GPG 2.x.  One workaround suggested in the bug report is to run the decryption inside of a tmux or screen session.  [More reading here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378021/gpg-cancelled-by-user).

Answer (score 6):

You can also be interested at the top answer in here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080204/gpg-problem-with-the-agent-permission-denied

basically the solution that worked for me too is:

```
gpg --decrypt --pinentry-mode=loopback <file>
```

Answer (score 5):

When migrating from one machine to another-

1. Check the gpg version and supported algorithms between the two systems.

   gpg --version
2. Check the presence of keys on both systems.

   gpg --list-keys

   **pub**   4096R/**62999779** 2020-08-04
   **sub**   4096R/**0F799997** 2020-08-04

   gpg --list-secret-keys

   **sec**   4096R/**62999779** 2020-08-04
   **ssb**   4096R/**0F799997** 2020-08-04

Check for the presence of same pair of *key ids* on the other machine. For decrypting, only secret key(sec) and secret sub key(ssb) will be needed.

If the key is not present on the other machine, export the keys in a file from the machine on which keys are present, scp the file and import the keys on the machine where it is missing.

Do not recreate the keys on the new machine with the same passphrase, name, user details as the newly generated key will have new unique id and "No secret key" error will still appear if source is using previously generated public key for encryption. So, export and import, this will ensure that same key id is used for decryption and encryption.

```
gpg --output gpg_pub_key --export <Email address>
gpg --output gpg_sec_key --export-secret-keys <Email address>
gpg --output gpg_sec_sub_key --export-secret-subkeys <Email address>

gpg --import gpg_pub_key
gpg --import gpg_sec_key
gpg --import gpg_sec_sub_key
```

Comment: What happens if one had to reinstall ones OS and create a new key from scratch with same name, user details etc.?

Answer (score 4):

Following this procedure worked for me.

To create gpg key.
`gpg --gen-key --homedir /etc/salt/gpgkeys`

export the public key, secret key, and secret subkey.

```
gpg --homedir /etc/salt/gpgkeys --export test-key > pub.key
gpg --homedir /etc/salt/gpgkeys --export-secret-keys test-key > sec.key
gpg --homedir /etc/salt/gpgkeys --export-secret-subkeys test-key > sub.key
```

Now import the keys using the following command.

```
gpg --import pub.key
gpg --import sec.key
gpg --import sub.key
```

Verify if the keys are imported.

```
gpg --list-keys
gpg --list-secret-keys
```

Create a sample file.

`echo "hahaha" > a.txt`

Encrypt the file using the imported key

`gpg --encrypt --sign --armor -r test-key a.txt`

To decrypt the file, use the following command.

`gpg --decrypt a.txt.asc`

Answer (score 2):

This just happened to me and the solution depends on the causing issue.
In my case I deleted the keys I initialized the password database with and hence the solution was to delete my .password_store folder in my home directory. If you cause this problem in the same way and have no passwords stored, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem, try to use root privileges, such as sudo gpg ...
I think that gpg elevated without permissions does not refer to file permissions, but system

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying to decrypt the key from a different user account via `su - <otherUser>`. (Like jayhendren suggests in his answer)

In my case, this happened because there would normally start a graphical `pinentry` prompt so I could enter the password to decrypt the key, but the `su -`ed to user had no access to the (graphical) X-Window-System that was currently running.

The solution was to simply issue in that same console (as the user under which the X Server was currently running):

`xhost +local:`

Which gives other **local users** access to the currently running (**local**) X-Server. After that, the `pinentry` prompt appeared, I could enter the password to decrypt the key and it worked...

Of course you can also forward X over `ssh` connections. For this look into `ssh`'s `-X` parameter (client side) and `X11Forwarding yes` (server side).

Comment: I think this is my problem. Any ideas on how to have it prompt on the tty and ignore pinentry?

Comment: You could try to add this to your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:
`pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-tty`
Install pinentry-tty if it is missing. Also, reload your connect-agent afterwards like so:
`gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye`

Comment: in my case i tried decryption with su to some other user and it failed. after that i am not able to encrypt with correct user as well not sure what went wrong. i am using pgp on linux rhel

Comment: Are you sure it worked before? Your comment does not provide enough information to derive any suggestions.

Comment: There are some pinnentry implementations that are quite broken, I've fixed this problem using update alternatives to select a working one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the default pinentry doesn't work remotely through ssh (even with the -X option). Solution:

`sudo update-alternatives --config pinentry`

Choose the `pinentry-curses` or `pinentry-tty` alternative.

Now you can use gpg remotely without workaround options like pinentry-mode.