# gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

Tags: encryption, ssis, gnupg

I am not able to decrypt my file without secret key. I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321712/gpg-decryption-fails-with-no-secret-key-error) question is asked on this before, solutions on this question did not help me.

This is my problem's scenario.

This error I receive on command prompt while using --decrypt command.

```
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

I have public key and a passphrase with me.
I have used following commands to check if there is secret key or not.

```
gpg --list-secret-keys

gpg --list-keys
```

Both the above commands returned blank result(no error). so I decided to import public key with --import .

```
gpg --import "C:\PATH\TO_MY_PUBLIC_KEY"
```

After --import command I can see public is imported. I could not find the way to deal with secret key. Is there any way I can find secret key or create new secret key.

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184865/gpg-decryption-failed-no-secret-key

Answer (score 20):

I also received blank output from the same 2 commands:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys
gpg --list-keys
```

I had reason to suspect this was to do with recent changes to the `~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx` file, which lead me to run the following 2 commands to re-import missing keys:

Re-import missing secret keys:

```
gpg --import < ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

Re-import missing public keys:

```
gpg --import < ~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
```

- Documentation for above commands: https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/kb/faq/missing-keys-after-migrating-to-gnupg-22#missing-secret-key-s-and-or-public-keys
- Broken `pubring.kbx`: https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/discussions/nightly/1415-gpg-keychain-broken-pubringkbx-file

Comment: After upgrading Ubuntu from `16.04` to `18.04`, I was now missing my secret keys. Re-importing using this method worked for me.

Comment: ` ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg` is empty

Comment: no such thing as secring.gpg or pubring.gpg on mine. is it a version thing?

Answer (score 11):

This message can also happen if your pinentry program isn't working properly, and thus gpg can't get the passphrase to unlock the decryption key. This has happened to me a couple of times. If this is the case, `gpg -d -v` will appear to select the correct key and then just hang for a while before giving up. This is it waiting for the pinentry that never actually returns.

The steps depend on your specific environment, but checking (or creating) the `pinentry-program` option in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` is a good place to start. In my case (on OS X with Homebrew-installed `gpg` and `pinentry-mac`) I had to create that file with the following contents:

```
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
```

And then run `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` to reload the configuration (`gpg-agent` should automatically restart).

You will likely need to adjust the path above for whatever your preferred pinentry program is. `locate pinentry` may be helpful to find what options you have installed, or `which your-pinentry-program-here` will tell you the full path if you already know the name.

Comment: macOS Big Sur user here, also using Homebrew. I was completely clueless about all the above. I guess I might have upgraded gpg via Homebrew and completely forgot to check if the `gpg-agent` configuration needed any changes... in any case, I wouldn't have the slightest idea where and what to change. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this. In the context I was running GPG (via [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/)) the "No pinentry" error line was getting swallowed, leaving only the "No secret key" line, which led me to believe that something subtle was wrong with the keys and `gpg.conf` I had just set up on this new machine.

Comment: Right, so because I was running commands over ssh on my laptop I just got the `No secret key` because `pinentry` is a desktop popup. Go to my physical laptop and it works fine. Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 5):

Very short version: you can't decrypt without the secret key.

GnuPG asks for the secret key (often used as synonym for private key if you read that somewhere), so the message was encrypted using public/private key cryptography.  You cannot decrypt the message using the public key, that's the basic principle behind public/private key cryptography. Secret keys *can* be protected with a passphrase, that's why you might have a passphrase (although you miss the key).

Ask for the private key if you are required to decrypt the message, or ask the sender to encrypt using symmetric cryptography and share the passphrase with you.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error but with a different solution to it, this was on OSX but I assume it will be similar on others.

The `gpg-agent` seemed to be the culprit as I realised that I never got the `pinentry` question for one of my keys.
Killing it with `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` solved that. And with the first call that needs it the gpg-agent will start automatically. And indeed the pinentry appeared and all was fine again.

Answer (score 3):

`gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --decrypt <yourfile>`
This allows pinentry to display its prompt on your screen.

Comment: this should be default behavior. Their custom prompt is just causing trouble all the time.

Answer (score 2):

In my case my gpg key had password and when I entered `git-crypt unlock` in vscode terminal which had a limited width and height it outputs

```
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
git-crypt: GPG error: Failed to decrypt
```

But when I try the same command on a **full terminal windows** it works like charm and prompts for getting password and so on.

Comment: I had the same problem when running the `gpg --decrypt...` command from a remote/ssh tmux screen

Answer (score 1):

you can ignore the error using: `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`

Answer (score 0):

In the event you import & then trust (ultimately) and can see the keys using `gpg --list-secret-keys` but when you go to decrypt it tells you it can't find the secret key, add the `--batch` to your decrypt command.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, both gpg (1.x) and gpg2 were installed on the system, and gpg 1.x doesn't have support for my ed25519 keys.

You'll know which algorithms are supported by looking at the version, grep for `Pubkey`

```
/usr/bin/gpg --version 
/usr/bin/gpg2 --version
```

If thats the case, try `gpg2 --list-secret-keys`

If that works, add an alias to .bashrc and symlink into ~/bin (for git)

```
echo "alias gpg='gpg2'" >> ~/.bashrc
ln -s /usr/bin/gpg2 $HOME/bin/gpg
. ~/.bashrc
```

Then, `gpg --list-secret-keys` output wasn't empty anymore.

Maybe it doesn't solve OP's issue, but hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I encrypted a file using symmetric encryption with passphrase and no secret key, and got the same error message, but in my case there was something much sillier going one.. **the encrypted package was corrupt..** make sure the package was properly formed if you are in the same situation.